# Argument order for '==' with Nullable<T>

Tags: c#, nullable, equals-operator, commutativity

The following two `C#` functions differ only in swapping the left/right order of arguments to the **equals** operator, `==`. (The type of `IsInitialized` is `bool`). Using **C# 7.1** and **.NET 4.7**.

```
static void A(ISupportInitialize x)
{
    if ((x as ISupportInitializeNotification)?.IsInitialized == true)
        throw null;
}
```

```
static void B(ISupportInitialize x)
{
    if (true == (x as ISupportInitializeNotification)?.IsInitialized)
        throw null;
}
```

But the **IL code** for the second one seems much more complex. For example, **B** is:

- 36 bytes longer (IL code);
- calls additional functions including `newobj` and `initobj`;
- declares four locals versus just one.

##### IL for function 'A'…

```
[0] bool flag
        nop
        ldarg.0
        isinst [System]ISupportInitializeNotification
        dup
        brtrue.s L_000e
        pop
        ldc.i4.0
        br.s L_0013
L_000e: callvirt instance bool [System]ISupportInitializeNotification::get_IsInitialized()
L_0013: stloc.0
        ldloc.0
        brfalse.s L_0019
        ldnull
        throw
L_0019: ret
```

##### IL for function 'B'…

```
[0] bool flag,
[1] bool flag2,
[2] valuetype [mscorlib]Nullable`1<bool> nullable,
[3] valuetype [mscorlib]Nullable`1<bool> nullable2
        nop
        ldc.i4.1
        stloc.1
        ldarg.0
        isinst [System]ISupportInitializeNotification
        dup
        brtrue.s L_0018
        pop
        ldloca.s nullable2
        initobj [mscorlib]Nullable`1<bool>
        ldloc.3
        br.s L_0022
L_0018: callvirt instance bool [System]ISupportInitializeNotification::get_IsInitialized()
        newobj instance void [mscorlib]Nullable`1<bool>::.ctor(!0)
L_0022: stloc.2
        ldloc.1
        ldloca.s nullable
        call instance !0 [mscorlib]Nullable`1<bool>::GetValueOrDefault()
        beq.s L_0030
        ldc.i4.0
        br.s L_0037
L_0030: ldloca.s nullable
        call instance bool [mscorlib]Nullable`1<bool>::get_HasValue()
L_0037: stloc.0
        ldloc.0
        brfalse.s L_003d
        ldnull
        throw
L_003d: ret
```

### Questions

1. Is there any functional, semantic, or other substantial runtime difference between **A** and **B**? (We're only interested in correctness here, not performance)
2. If they are *not* functionally equivalent, what are the runtime conditions that can expose an observable difference?
3. If they *are* functional equivalents, what is **B** doing (that always ends up with the same result as **A**), and what triggered its spasm? Does **B** have branches that can never execute?
4. If the difference is explained by the difference between what appears on the **left** side of `==`, (here, a property referencing expression versus a literal value), can you indicate a section of the C# spec that describes the details.
5. Is there a reliable rule-of-thumb that can be used to predict the bloated **IL** at coding-time, and thus avoid creating it?

BONUS. How does the respective final JITted `x86` or `AMD64` code for each stack up?

---

### [edit]

Additional notes based on feedback in the comments. First, a third variant was proposed, but it gives identical IL as **A** (for both `Debug` and `Release` builds). Sylistically, however, the **C#** for the new one does seem sleeker than **A**:

```
static void C(ISupportInitialize x)
{
    if ((x as ISupportInitializeNotification)?.IsInitialized ?? false)
        throw null;
}
```

Here also is the `Release` IL for each function. Note that the asymmetry **A**/**C** vs. **B** is still evident with the `Release` IL, so the original question still stands.

##### Release IL for functions 'A', 'C'…

```
        ldarg.0
        isinst [System]ISupportInitializeNotification
        dup
        brtrue.s L_000d
        pop
        ldc.i4.0
        br.s L_0012
L_000d: callvirt instance bool [System]ISupportInitializeNotification::get_IsInitialized()
        brfalse.s L_0016
        ldnull
        throw
L_0016: ret
```

##### Release IL for function 'B'…

```
[0] valuetype [mscorlib]Nullable`1<bool> nullable,
[1] valuetype [mscorlib]Nullable`1<bool> nullable2
        ldc.i4.1
        ldarg.0
        isinst [System]ISupportInitializeNotification
        dup
        brtrue.s L_0016
        pop
        ldloca.s nullable2
        initobj [mscorlib]Nullable`1<bool>
        ldloc.1
        br.s L_0020
L_0016: callvirt instance bool [System]ISupportInitializeNotification::get_IsInitialized()
        newobj instance void [mscorlib]Nullable`1<bool>::.ctor(!0)
L_0020: stloc.0
        ldloca.s nullable
        call instance !0 [mscorlib]Nullable`1<bool>::GetValueOrDefault()
        beq.s L_002d
        ldc.i4.0
        br.s L_0034
L_002d: ldloca.s nullable
        call instance bool [mscorlib]Nullable`1<bool>::get_HasValue()
L_0034: brfalse.s L_0038
        ldnull
        throw
L_0038: ret
```

Lastly, a version using new **C# 7** syntax was mentioned which seems to produce the cleanest IL of all:

```
static void D(ISupportInitialize x)
{
    if (x is ISupportInitializeNotification y && y.IsInitialized)
        throw null;
}
```

##### Release IL for function 'D'…

```
[0] class [System]ISupportInitializeNotification y
        ldarg.0
        isinst [System]ISupportInitializeNotification
        dup
        stloc.0
        brfalse.s L_0014
        ldloc.0
        callvirt instance bool [System]ISupportInitializeNotification::get_IsInitialized()
        brfalse.s L_0014
        ldnull
        throw
L_0014: ret
```

---

### [edit 2023]

Another new syntax, *"[property pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#property-pattern)"*, is available starting in **C# 8**. The following gives the same "best" **IL** as example **D**:

```cs
static void E(ISupportInitialize x)
{
    if (x is ISupportInitializeNotification { IsInitialized: true })
        throw null;
}
```

Comment: In the first case the compiler is able to short-circuit the entire check when it sees that the first call on the *left* side is null, which means the left argument is null no matter what else it contains. Comparing it to anything other than null is guaranteed to be false.

Comment: In the second case though the left part is true so no short-circuiting is involved. The compiler *has* to calculate the result of the entire expression. If you check the calls, it is creating a nullable object due to the use of `?.`, and trying to call IsInitialized if the nullable has a value

Comment: Can you get rid of `?` operator in your examples and check again, will it gives the same results?

Comment: @ASprin surely that code wouldn't be probative for this case. Omitting `?` changes everything, since then you also no longer need `== true`, and you'd end up with `if ((x as ISupportInitializeNotification).IsInitialized)…`, and furthermore at that point you might as well just do `if (((ISupportInitializeNotification)x).IsInitialized)…`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's a good *description* of the IL the compiler happens to end up producing here. For example, I now notice that **B's** problems begin right away: It gets trapped by its first instruction `ldc.i4.1` since that commits it to eventually doing a non-nullable compare. But you stop short of explaining why the same short-circuit isn't detected on the right side… I do realize `C#` guarantees left-to-right evaluation order perhaps in force here due to the possibilty of side-effecting `IsInitialized`, but surely failure of left side `true` could be precluded...? Optimization bug?

Comment: Any reason why you'd want to place the `true` literal on the left side of the evaluation? Other than a stylistic desire to make the code look C++-like, that is?

Comment: Not for me, but I *was* wondering if anyone was going to bring that up. As you probably know, there's actually a legitimate reason to always put literals on the left in `C` / `C++`: it eliminates the possibility of unintentional assignment (via `=`) when equality (`==`) is intended, a nasty bug which can be hard to track down since `if (a = b)…` looks so similar to `if (a ==  b)…` (It's a moot issue in `C#`). So the reason instead is that I generally like to have a vague notion of the IL I'll be getting as I write `C#` code, so surprises I don't understand require some investigation of "why."

Comment: This is code generated with optimizations turned off. You should expect it to be not optimized.

Comment: You could use the idiomatic combination of the null-propagating and the null-coalescing operator: `if ((x as ISupportInitializeNotification)?.IsInitialized ?? false)`. Even better the new is-expressions with patterns: `if (x is ISupportInitializeNotification y && y.IsInitialized)`. They both result in equal or shorter IL than A.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks, I edited the post to include `Release` IL for all examples, including the two additional suggested by @Johnbot. The assymetry noted in the original question persists.

Comment: I would say you have found a case where the C# compiler is not producing the best output possible. Almost a bug.

Comment: What type does `IsInitialized` return? Is it `bool`, `Nullable<bool>` or something else? What version of VC#? For now, VTC for no [mcve]. I really don't see anything like this in the spec and in a test with `bool`, there's no difference.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev `ISupportInitialize` and `ISupportInitializeNotification` are both defined in the .NET namespace `System.ComponentModel`, provided by the **CLR** in `System.dll`. I omitted this information since I assumed it would be well-known and thus would only create clutter here. I have now modified the post to indicate this at the top. I believe the minimal example requirement is satisfied by the contrast between *A* and *B*, which are indeed complete, minimal, and verifiable. Please provide additional remarks if you aren't able to retract your VTC. Thanks.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Re-checking your note, I've also now added the `VC#` and `.NET` versions I'm using.

Comment: Just small comment on recent edit - property pattern matching was available since C# 8 [some docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns), C# 10 only improved this feature to support succinct nested properties matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was curious about the answer and took a look at the c# 6 specification (no clue where the c# 7 spec is hosted). Full disclaimer: I do not guarantee that my answer is correct, because I did not write the c# spec/compiler and my understanding of the internals is limited.

Yet I think that the answer lies in the resultion of the [overloadable](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#overload-resolution) `==` operator. The best applicable overload for `==` is determined by using the rules for [better function members](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#better-function-member).

From the spec:

> Given an argument list A with a set of argument expressions {E1, E2,
>   ..., En} and two applicable function members Mp and Mq with parameter
>   types {P1, P2, ..., Pn} and {Q1, Q2, ..., Qn}, Mp is defined to be a
>   better function member than Mq if
>
> for each argument, the implicit conversion from Ex to Qx is not better
>   than the implicit conversion from Ex to Px, and for at least one
>   argument, the conversion from Ex to Px is better than the conversion
>   from Ex to Qx.

What caught my eye is the argument list `{E1, E2, .., En}`. If you compare a `Nullable<bool>` to a `bool` the argument list should be something like `{Nullable<bool> a, bool b}`and for that argument list the `Nullable<bool>.Equals(object o)` method seems to be the best function, because it only takes one implicit conversion from `bool` to `object`.

However if you revert the order of the argument list to `{bool a, Nullable<bool> b}` the `Nullable<bool>.Equals(object o)` method no longer is the best function, because now you would have to convert from `Nullable<bool>` to `bool` in the first argument and then from `bool` to `object` in the second argument. That's why for case *A* a different overload is selected which seems to result in cleaner IL code.

Again this is an explanation that satisfies my own curiosity and *seems* to be in line with the c# spec. But I have yet to figure out how to debug the compiler to see what's actually going on.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the 1st operand is converted to the 2nd's type for the purpose of comparison.

The excess operations in case B involve constructing a `Nullable<bool>(true)`. While in case A, to compare something to a `true`/`false`, there's a single IL instruction (`brfalse.s`) that does it.

I couldn't find the specific reference in the [C# 5.0 spec](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029). ***7.10 Relational and type-testing operators*** refers to ***7.3.4 Binary operator overload resolution*** that in turn refers to ***7.5.3 Overload resolution***, but the latter one is very vague.

Comment: Very vague? That's the most detailed part of the C# spec. Perhaps you meant *arcane*, since it's nearly impossible to make sense of by an average human reader, but that's another matter altogether.