# Checking a bool value with a generic in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following method:

```
void Test<T>(T Result)
```

and I need to implement something like this:

```
if Result is null, or T is a bool and that bool is false
```

I tried to do something like

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool)
{
  if ((bool)Result == false)   // doesn't work
  if (Result as bool == false) // doesn't work
```

how can I implement this without creating two methods?

Comment: what you are asking for is called template specialization. The closest equivalent to this in C# is overloading, see the answer I proposed as duplicate.

Comment: Adding a constraint to you method `Test<T>(T Result) where T : IComparable`  makes it *comparable*. `Result.CompareTo(true)==0`

Comment: `if (someBool == false)` is never useful anyway. Just use `if(!someBool)`

Comment: @oerkelens I think you mean `if(!someBool)` which is not more readable.

Comment: @L.B of course!

Comment: yes, I meant !result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try casting it to a nullable `bool` and test it:

```
public void Test<T>(T result)
{
    var asBool = result as bool?;
    if (!asBool.HasValue || !asBool.Value)
    {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

(I changed `Result` to `result` since it is a parameter)

Comment: this works! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution which casts `T` to `bool` via `object` (you can't cast `T` to `bool` directly):

```
if ((bool)(object)result == false)
{
    // bool with value set to false
}
```

You might also want to consider benchmarking all solutions proposed in the answers if performance is a concern—see ["Performance surprise with “as” and nullable types"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583050/performance-surprise-with-as-and-nullable-types).

Comment: Performance is not an issue here but thanks for the link, it's interesting!

Answer (score 0):

You can test with

```
if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(result, default(T))) {
    ...
}
```

For `bool`, `default(T)` is `false`, for reference types it is `null`. For all other types, it is a value represented by all bits set to `0`. I.e. for numeric types it will be `0`.