# Cast then check or check then cast?

Tags: c#, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Casting vs using the ‘as’ keyword in the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr)

Which method is regarded as best practice?

Cast first?

```
public string Describe(ICola cola)
{
    var coke = cola as CocaCola;
    if (coke != null)
    {
        string result;
        // some unique coca-cola only code here.
        return result;
    }
    var pepsi = cola as Pepsi;
    if (pepsi != null)
    {
        string result;
        // some unique pepsi only code here.
        return result;
    }
}
```

Or should I check first, cast later?

```
public string Describe(ICola cola)
{
    if (cola is CocaCola)
    {
        var coke = (CocaCola) cola;
        string result;
        // some unique coca-cola only code here.
        return result;
    }
    if (cola is Pepsi)
    {
        var pepsi = (Pepsi) cola;
        string result;
        // some unique pepsi only code here.
        return result;
    }
}
```

Can you see any other way to do this?

Comment: See the perfect answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/496167/52277 for similar question

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the object may or may not be of the type you want then the `as` operator (your first method) is better in two ways:

- Readability and ease of maintenance: you are only specifying the type once
- Performance: you are only performing the cast once, instead of twice. (Trivia: when you use the `is` keyword, the C# compiler internally translates it to `as`, ie. `coke is Cola` is equivalent to `(coke as Cola) != null`)

If the object should always be of the requested type then just do `(Coke)cola` and let it throw an exception if that's not the case.

Answer (score 7):

The first (casting first via as) is slightly more efficient, so in that regard, it ~might~ be a best practice.

However, the code above, in general, displays a bit of "code smell".  I'd consider refactoring any code that follows this pattern, if possible.  Have `ICola` provide a describe method, and let it describe itself.  This avoids the type checks and duplicated code...

Comment: Agree about the code smell - from the example this looks like a problem that could be better solved by polymorphism rather than by wildly casting objects about.

Comment: I agree with the code smell. In this case however, I don't want methods in my view permeating my Cola objects.

Comment: @jamesrom: Well, I did try to answer your question, first, before mentioning that (as is faster).  However, I would really think about how you could eliminate the duplicated code- can your View pass in a delegate to handle the "specific" code more efficiently, maybe?

Comment: I came here to learn about similar problems I was having. I do not understand how to do this `ICola` code sniffing, and I don't know what to google search on. What is this called, and how would one implement it?

Answer (score 4):

This example uses a local parameter which is safe, but many times the type check is applied to fields (member variables) of a class.  In which case "as"-then-check is safe, but "is"-then-cast creates a gratuitous race condition.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's more efficient 1st way: *Cast and then check*, but...

Lots of time you develop for developers, and in my opinion, it's much more readable *checking first and then casting...*

Answer (score 1):

Let me just put it out there. But I think neither is right :) In your particular example, why have an interface at all then? I would put a "Describe" method on your ICola interface, then implement the describe logic in your CocaCola and Pepsi classes that implement the interface.

So basically put that `// some unique <some cola> only code here.` into the implementing classes.

But to answer your question, I think check-then-cast is more appropriate.

Comment: That is what I would do if I could. But say, for example, that I didn't want my view logic permeating my Cola objects.

Comment: In that case, use some decorator or visitor-based solution for example, anything is better than manually inspecting the runtime-type of objects. I even think view logic would be less evil than casting and switching on types all over the place.