# When checking for a type, is it better to use "is" with "as" or just "as" and a null check?

Tags: c#, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Casting vs using the 'as' keyword in the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr)
>   [Cast then check or check then cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550625/cast-then-check-or-check-then-cast)

Assume the following code setup:

```
public class BaseFoo { ... }
public class DerivedFoo : BaseFoo { ... }
```

Now, I have a `BaseFoo` object named `foo` that may or may not actually be of type `DerivedFoo`. If it is a `DerivedFoo` object, I need to add a couple of steps to how I process it. Is there any non-subjective reason to prefer one of the following code snippets above the other:

**Option 1:**

```
if (foo is DerivedFoo)
{
    var dfoo = foo as DerivedFoo;
    // Continue processing...
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
var dfoo = foo as DerivedFoo;
if (dfoo != null)
{
    // Continue processing...
}
```

Personally, I think that Option 1 is more readable and concise, but I'm  wondering if there is any performance hit or behavioral difference that I'm missing.

Comment: This is a dupe of a dupe, go with option 2 otherwise you are doing twice the work

Comment: Where's the dupe? I couldn't find it.

Comment: This smells a lot... Specifically, it breaks the substitution principle.

Comment: @Niklas B. - I would be open to alternative suggestions.

Comment: In Option 1 why are you using the `as` operator, rather than a direct cast?

Comment: @FishBasketGordo: As per the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), the `DerivedFoo` must not require any "special treatment". Without seeing the classes, we can't tell you how this should be fixed, obviously. A simple solution would be to add a `prepare()` method to `BaseFoo`, which does nothing by default but can be overriden by the subclass.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo: Unfortunately with `as` and `is` dupes are hard to find - I have seen this question several times though, I'm sure someone can find them

Answer (score -3):

To check if a object is of a certain class, the operator 'is' is all it takes.

```
if (object is ClassName)
{ }
```

Will return flat true if it is, false if null or trully false.

Comment: That doesn't address Option 2 at all

Comment: .... Oh Really? 
He asked what is  the most viable regarding perfomance and my answer is all that it takes.

Comment: Next time back up what you say @niklas-b ....

if (object is ClassName) can be applied both to Basefoo and to DerivedFoo

Comment: I hadn't downvoted, because I think this is a valid answer, but now I'm tempted to do so due to your harsh response.