# More readable way to check if class IS NOT of a type?

Tags: c#

To check if an object *is* of a given type in `C#`:

```cs
if(myObj is MyClass)
{
     //....
}
```

To check if it *is not* of a given type:

```cs
if(!(myObj is MyClass))
{
     //....
}
```

Is there a more readable way to express the same logic?

For example, if I could write this it would be easier to read.

```cs
if(myObj is not MyClass)
{
     //....
}
```

Comment: Might want to check this out if you're okay with casting and then checking for null: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550625/cast-then-check-or-check-then-cast

Comment: You would like VB.NET better.  That's fine, a very capable .NET language.  It has a much more sensible precedence for the Not operator, no parentheses required.

Comment: if(myObj is MyClass == false) ?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter you should post that as an answer. best approach I've seen so far (been googling this).

Comment: @HansPassant While I'd take a *few* things from VB.NET ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take the same approach and make it more verbose:

```
If (myObj is MyClass == false) ;
```

Comment: I went with this approach. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can try using some extention method like this, just to make it *more readable* as you want:

```
public static class ObjectExtension
{
    public static bool IsNot<T>(this object o)
    {
        return !(o is T);
    }
}
//Use it
if(myObj.IsNot<MyClass>()){
  //...
}
```

Comment: I've never seen this done before, thanks. Reminds me of traits in PHP.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini that's some combination of `extension method` and `generics`, I think it's just the most beautiful work-around.

Comment: You might wish to add a generic constraint to ensure that this is not used with value types. Edit:  I guess `is` works with value types after all.  But will this cause boxing?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway wow, after your comment, I've done some test, it's still useful for testing on `struct`, some object has `struct` boxed inside it, we still need to check that case. I don't think there is any problem here.