# Difference between Convert.ToString() and .ToString()

Tags: c#, type-conversion, tostring

What is the difference between `Convert.ToString()` and `.ToString()`?

I found many differences online, but what's the major difference?

Comment: You say you got many differences on the web and later you ask if its for this specific reason only?   What else did you find on the web?

Comment: Convert.ToString() has an overload that allows to use CultureInfo, while .ToString() doesn't have such overload.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

`Convert.ToString()` handles `null`, while `ToString()` doesn't.

Comment: good.. For this specific reason only they using. two methods?

Comment: Also, semi-related, see this answer for more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr/496167#496167

Comment: More information about the differences using JustDecompile/Reflector : http://www.kodefuguru.com/post/2011/06/14/Deeper-into-Convert-ToString.aspx

Comment: Do you want `null` to return an empty string or throw an exception? It's kind of like the difference between casting and using `as`: silent conversion.

Comment: @Ubikuity : the link is broken

Comment: Here is a copy from Internet Archive of the blog post I was mentioning: http://web.archive.org/web/20110828105257/http://www.kodefuguru.com/post/2011/06/14/Deeper-into-Convert-ToString.aspx

Comment: Love it when I read a complete, direct-to-the-point, killer answer.

Comment: To be more precise, it returns an empty string. I think this is not clear from your answer.

Comment: Note, as alluded to in the question, this is just the _major_ difference between the two. As Alexander mentions, there are other subtler differences. For example, I just created a bug in some code when I thought I could use them interchangeably on an enum; but `.ToString()` gave me equivalent text and `Convert.ToString` gave me the integer value (converted to a string).

Answer (score 70):

Calling `ToString()` on an object presumes that the object is not null (since an object needs to exist to call an instance method on it). `Convert.ToString(obj)` doesn't need to presume the object is not null (as it is a static method on the Convert class), but instead will return `String.Empty` if it *is* null.

Comment: var arg = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT");

string _arg = Convert.ToString(arg); _arg is not returing String.Empty when arg is null. why?

Comment: @Nilaa you might want to open another question asking this, instead of in comment. My first question is what *does* it return when arg is null? My first thought is that "arg" is actually of type "string" already, so you're calling the overload of Convert.ToString(...), that just returns what you pass to it. This discussion is in regards to the "object" overload of the method.

Comment: @Roshe Yeah, I just got bit by this.  `Convert.ToString(string value)` returns `null` if the argument is `null`.  `Convert.ToString(object value)` returns `String.Empty` if the argument is `null`.

Answer (score 26):

In addition to other answers about handling `null` values, `Convert.ToString` tries to use `IFormattable` and `IConvertible` interfaces before calling base `Object.ToString`.

Example:

```
class FormattableType : IFormattable
{
    private double value = 0.42;

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (formatProvider == null)
        {
            // ... using some IOC-containers
            // ... or using CultureInfo.CurrentCulture / Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
            formatProvider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        }

        // ... doing things with format
        return value.ToString(formatProvider);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Convert.ToString(new FormattableType()); // 0.42
new FormattableType().ToString();        // 0,42
```

Comment: This should be added to the correct answer because it is quite important information.

Comment: Just as a supplement - basing on [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1801) `IConvertible` takes precedence over `IFormattable`, which in turn takes precedence over `Object.ToString()` implementation.

Answer (score 12):

Lets understand the difference via this example:

```
int i= 0;
MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(i));
```

We can convert the integer `i` using `i.ToString ()` or `Convert.ToString`. So what’s the difference?

The basic difference between them is the `Convert` function handles NULLS while `i.ToString ()` does not; it will throw a NULL reference exception error. So as good coding practice using `convert` is always safe.

Comment: you example is a little invalid as int can never be null

Answer (score 6):

You can create a class and override the `toString` method to do anything you want.

For example- you can create a class *"MyMail"* and override the `toString` method to send an email or do some other operation instead of writing the current object.

The `Convert.toString` converts the specified value to its equivalent string representation.

Comment: Convert.ToString actually a safe method which checks for null and if value is not null it simply calls ToString method on it. So In any case, if you have overriden ToString method, Your overriden ToString method will be called.

Comment: And this null safety only helps if you are dealing with classes. Value types can't be null and so we can safely call ToString method on them.

Answer (score 6):

The methods are "basically" the same, **except** handling **null**.

```
Pen pen = null; 
Convert.ToString(pen); // No exception thrown
pen.ToString(); // Throws NullReferenceException
```

From MSDN :
[**Convert.ToString Method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Converts the specified value to its equivalent string representation.

[**Object.ToString**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns a string that represents the current object.

Comment: "prints nothing"? what is nothing? `null`, `""` or `"null"`?

Answer (score 5):

```
object o=null;
string s;
s=o.toString();
//returns a null reference exception for string  s.

string str=convert.tostring(o);
//returns an empty string for string str and does not throw an exception.,it's 
//better to use convert.tostring() for good coding
```

Answer (score 5):

I agree with [@**Ryan**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2828180/5259296)'s answer. By the way, starting with C#6.0 for this purpose you can use:

```
someString?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
```

or

```
$"{someString}"; // I do not recommend this approach, although this is the most concise option.
```

instead of

```
Convert.ToString(someString);
```

Answer (score 3):

In `Convert.ToString()`, the Convert handles either a `NULL` value or not but in `.ToString()` it does not handles a `NULL` value and a `NULL` reference exception error. So it is in good practice to use `Convert.ToString()`.

Answer (score 3):

**For Code lovers this is the best answer.**

```
    .............. Un Safe code ...................................
    Try
        ' In this code we will get  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception
        Dim a As Object
        a = Nothing
        a.ToString()
    Catch ex As NullReferenceException
        Response.Write(ex.Message)
    End Try


    '............... it is a safe code..............................
    Dim b As Object
    b = Nothing
    Convert.ToString(b)
```

Comment: I am pretty satisfied with your answer. Hence +1. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`Convert.ToString(strName)` will handle null-able values and `strName.Tostring()` will not handle null value and throw an exception.

So It is better to use `Convert.ToString()` then `.ToString();`

Answer (score 2):

`ToString()` can not handle null values and `convert.ToString()` can handle values which are null, so when you want your system to handle null value use `convert.ToString()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
ToString() Vs Convert.ToString()
```

> Similarities :-

Both are used to convert a specific type to string i.e int to string, float to string or an object to string.

> Difference :-

`ToString()` can't handle null while in case with `Convert.ToString()` will handle null value.

Example :

```
namespace Marcus
{
    class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    class Startup
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Employee e = new Employee();
            e = null;

            string s = e.ToString(); // This will throw an null exception
            s = Convert.ToString(e); // This will throw null exception but it will be automatically handled by Convert.ToString() and exception will not be shown on command window.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Convert.ToString` do not handle `Null Exception`. it simply do: `return value == null ? string.Empty : value.ToString()`

Answer (score 2):

Here both the methods are used to convert the string but the basic difference between them is: `Convert` function handles `NULL`, while `i.ToString()` does not it will throw a `NULL reference exception error.` So as good coding practice using `convert` is always safe.

Let's see example:

```
string s;
object o = null;
s = o.ToString(); 
//returns a null reference exception for s. 

string s;
object o = null;
s = Convert.ToString(o); 
//returns an empty string for s and does not throw an exception.
```

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToString(value)` first tries casting obj to [IConvertible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible), then [IFormattable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformattable) to call corresponding `ToString(...)` methods. If instead the parameter value was `null` then return `string.Empty`. As a last resort, return `obj.ToString()` if nothing else worked.

It's worth noting that `Convert.ToString(value)` *can* return `null` if for example `value.ToString()` returns null.

See [.Net reference source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/60a4f8b853f60a424e36c7bf60f9b5b5f1973ed1/mscorlib/system/convert.cs#L1797)

Answer (score 0):

i wrote this code and compile it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 1;
        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(a));
    }
}
```

by using 'reverse engineering' ([ilspy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy)) i find out 'object.ToString()' and 'Convert.ToString(obj)' do exactly one thing.
infact 'Convert.ToString(obj)' call 'object.ToString()' so **'object.ToString()' is faster.**

> [Object.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
class System.Object
{
    public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return Number.FormatInt32(this, null, NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider));
    }
}
```

> [Conver.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToString_System_Int32_):

```
class System.Convert
{
    public static string ToString(object value)
    {
        return value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert.Tostring() function handles the NULL whereas the .ToString() method does not. visit [here](https://devbloggies.blogspot.com/2019/07/difference-between-convert.tostring-and-.tostring-method-in-c-sharp.html).

Answer (score 0):

In C# if you declare a string variable and if you don’t assign any value to that variable, then by default that variable takes a null value. In such a case, if you use the ToString() method then your program will throw the null reference exception. On the other hand, if you use the Convert.ToString() method then your program will not throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

- `Convert.Tostring()` basically just calls the following `value == null ? String.Empty: value.ToString()`
- `(string)variable` will only *cast* when there is an *implicit* or *explicit* operator on what you are casting
- `ToString()` can be *overriden* by the type (it has control over what it does), if not it results in the name of the type

Obviously if an object is *null*, you can't access the instance member `ToString()`, it will cause an exception