# DataRow: Select cell value by a given column name

Tags: c#, .net, excel, datarow

I have a problem with a DataRow that I'm really struggling with.

The datarow is read in from an Excel spreadsheet using an OleDbConnection.

If I try to select data from the DataRow using the column name, it returns DBNull even though there is data there.

But it's not quite that simple.

`datarow.Table.Columns[5].ColumnName` returns "my column".
`datarow["my column"]` returns DBNull.
`datarow[5]` returns 500.
`datarow[datarow.Table.Columns[5].ColumnName]` returns DBNull. (just to make sure its not a typo!)

I could just select things from the datarow using the column number, but I dislike doing that since if the column ordering changes, the software will break.

Comment: What does your spreadsheet look like? Does it have any blank rows at top? What is your connection string?  What's the smallest amount of code you need to reproduce it that we could look it? (incl. sample sheet)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Which version of .NET are you using? Since .NET 3.5, there's an assembly System.Data.DataSetExtensions, which contains various useful extensions for dataTables, dataRows and the like.

You can try using

```
row.Field<type>("fieldName");
```

if that doesn't work, you can do this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
var myColumn = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().SingleOrDefault(col => col.ColumnName == "myColumnName");
if (myColumn != null)
{
    // just some roww
    var tableRow = table.AsEnumerable().First();
    var myData = tableRow.Field<string>(myColumn);
    // or if above does not work
    myData = tableRow.Field<string>(table.Columns.IndexOf(myColumn));
}
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer as it led me to work out what was going on. Turns out that I'd when using Quick Watch, I typed the wrong column id. Typing the correct column id returned null even though there was data in the row. I'm not entirely sure why it was returning null, but I'm guessing it has something to do with interpreting data types, because this was the only row with a non-null value, and replacing null with 0 in all the other rows made it return the correct value of this row too.

Comment: Look at Jimmys answer. It is easier and does the job. I had no luck with this one, using .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Answer (score 77):

This must be a new feature or something, otherwise I'm not sure why it hasn't been mentioned.

You can access the value in a column in a `DataRow` object using `row["ColumnName"]`:

```
DataRow row = table.Rows[0];
string rowValue = row["ColumnName"].ToString();
```

Comment: If the data entry is NULL I believe an error will be thrown when ToString is called.

Comment: @Zorgarath, true fact. You'll also get an error if `table` has no rows.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I knew this was possible but i couldn't remember the syntax and you can't see it by evaluating

Answer (score 10):

I find it easier to access it by doing the following:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Table.Rows.Count-1; i++) //Looping through rows
        {
            var myValue = Table.Rows[i]["MyFieldName"]; //Getting my field value

        }
```

Answer (score 8):

Hint

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Column#1", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Column#2", typeof(string));
table.Rows.Add(5, "Cell1-1");
table.Rows.Add(130, "Cell2-2");
```

**EDIT: Added more**

```
string cellValue = table.Rows[0].GetCellValueByName<string>("Column#2");

public static class DataRowExtensions
{
    public static T GetCellValueByName<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName)
    {
        int index = row.Table.Columns.IndexOf(columnName);
        return (index < 0 || index > row.ItemArray.Count()) 
                  ? default(T) 
                  : (T) row[index];        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On top of what Jimmy said, you can also make the select generic by using `Convert.ChangeType` along with the necessary null checks:

```
public T GetColumnValue<T>(DataRow row, string columnName)
  {
        T value = default(T);
        if (row.Table.Columns.Contains(columnName) && row[columnName] != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row[columnName].ToString()))
        {
            value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(row[columnName].ToString(), typeof(T));
        }

        return value;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the column value in VB.net

```
Dim row As DataRow = fooTable.Rows(0)
Dim temp = Convert.ToString(row("ColumnName"))
```

And in C# you can use [Jimmy's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24314787/4984818), just be careful while converting it to `ToString()`. It can throw null exception if the data is null
instead Use `Convert.ToString(your_expression)` to avoid null exception [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2828180/4984818)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0;i < Table.Rows.Count;i++)
{
      Var YourValue = Table.Rows[i]["ColumnName"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful on datatype. If not match it will throw an error.

```
var fieldName = dataRow.Field<DataType>("fieldName");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:
Assume sqlDt contains the DataTable, then this will give you the content of the
column named "aaa" in row is:

```
Dim fldContent = sqlDte.Rows(iz).ItemArray(sqlDte.Columns.Item("aaa").Ordinal)
Console.WriteLine("aaa = " & fldContent)
```

Edited code formatting