# How to get row value by just giving column name in DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

Is it possible to get a row value by giving column name when DataTable holds a single row, without iteration.

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string strCity = row["City"].ToString();
}
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZjr7.png)

I need Something like below without loop when we have only one row,

```
String cn=row["ColumnName"].ToString()
```

Comment: What is a row value? Rows consist of columns so you should say what column you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataRow: Select cell value by a given column name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119993/datarow-select-cell-value-by-a-given-column-name)

Answer (score 22):

This is the way:

```
string Text = dataTable.Rows[0]["ColumnName"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use following code to get the value of the first row of the DataTable without iteration:

```
string strCity = string.Empty;
if (yourDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    strCity = yourDataTable.Rows[0]["City"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert.ToString(row["ColumnName"]);

Answer (score 0):

This is attempting to index the row itself:

```
row["ColumnName"].ToString()
```

What you're looking for is to index the items *within* the row:

```
row.Item["ColumnName"].ToString()
```

> when DataTable holds a single row, without iteration

If you're *guaranteed* that there is a row, you can reference it directly:

```
dt.Rows[0].Item["ColumnName"].ToString()
```

As with any indexing, you should probably do some bounds checking before trying to index it though.

Comment: Note that there is no `row.Item` in DataRow

Comment: it not row.Item ... it's row.ItemArray

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();    
sqlDa.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        { 
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                html.Append(row.Field<Int32>("Columname"));

            }
        }
```