# Get null value from Excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I'm importing an excel file into a DataTable, and then getting the information i need from each subsequent DataRow.

My problem is that when i access a DataRow, on this specific DataTable, some  fields contain values, but everything else is just null

Please see attached file

Do you have any idea how can I fix this issue?

[image: Value in excel file]

[image: result]

Comment: They look like they can expand more in the debugger screen, what extra does it show if u press the arrow at [11] and [12]?

Comment: why not use `.Value` or `.Value2`?

Comment: How are you importing? You didn't post any code, how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: @S.Fragkos if i press the arrow i get static members

Comment: @Boxed i cant use .value because i read data from a datarow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is related to IMEX value i changed from 2 to 1 in the connection string :)

string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in the answer below, if you give a value of “0” to real null columns the value of a non null column returns as per normal.

[DataRow: Select cell value by a given column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119993/datarow-select-cell-value-by-a-given-column-name)

So my guess is add a value of “0” to your column that actually has no value.

```
dcc[3] = 0;
```

Then it’s this as you did.

```
string XNR_N = dcc[11].toString();
```

Try that otherwise I think we could do with more information.

Comment: Thank you for your support,I try it but not working also i fill the null columns in the excel file but i have the same result the last 2 columns dcc[11] and dcc[12] are null