# NullReferenceException was unhandled - How to resolve it

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MANINOTEBOOK\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Casesheet");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select PatientID from FTR where PatientID='" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
    textBox2.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    if (textBox2.Text == textBox1.Text)
    {
        Consultation cs = new Consultation(textBox1.Text);
        cs.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
    }            
}
```

When i compile this code i get an error "NullReferenceException was unhandled". I dont know how to resolve it. I need to check the value generated in the "execute scalar" command is null or not.  Kindly help me in resolving this problem.

Comment: Do you get an error when you **compile** the code, or when you **run** the code? Since it's probably when you **run** the code, please indicate what line of code is causing the error. Your stack-trace, or your debugger will assist you with this.

Comment: I doubt that you get the error when you *compile* the code. I suspect you get the error when you *run* the code.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the  exception was raised on `ToString`:

```
textBox2.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

That happens when no patient with that ID was found in database because then [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) returns null. So you should check for null:

```
Object patID = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(patID != null)
{
    String patientID = patID.ToString();
    // ...
}
```

**Note**: You should not concatenate strings to build your sql query but use [`SqlParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead to avoid [**SQL-Injection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

this can return null if the result was empty. you should change it to

```
 (cmd.ExecuteScalar() ?? "").ToString()
```

so it is changed to an empty string if it is null

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference* between .ToString() and Convert.ToString()

Convert.ToString() handles null values, i.e. If you give null input, it would give you back an empty string.

Whereas, .ToString() Which you've used - throws an exception when a null value is passed.

so, you could simply choose to rephrase your code like so:

```
textBox2.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

** Not the only difference. Read more here: [Difference between Convert.ToString() and .ToString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828154/difference-between-convert-tostring-and-tostring)

Comment: That's *a* difference between the two, but not the only difference.

Comment: Agreed. I felt in the scope of this question, this difference is important. Thanks for mentioning, I'll add a disclaimer.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MANINOTEBOOK\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Casesheet");
  try
  {
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select PatientID from FTR where PatientID='" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
    textBox2.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    if (textBox2.Text == textBox1.Text)
    {
        Consultation cs = new Consultation(textBox1.Text);
        cs.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
    }    
  } 
   catch(NullReferenceException ex)
   {
   Console.Write(ex.message);
   }     
}
```

you can catch your exception by putting try catch block and if you want to find out value generated then put breakpoint in code.