# How to convert nullable int to string

Tags: c#

I need to convert the nullable int to string

```
int? a = null;
string str = a.ToString();
```

How can I perform this action without an exception?
I need to get the string as "Null".
Please guide me.

Comment: Use Convert.ToString(a) instead of a.ToString() See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828154/difference-between-convert-tostring-and-tostring

Comment: @animaonline "How to convert nullable int to Google?"

Comment: Ignore the snarky coments.  Apparently, they haven't read [Kicking off the Summer of Love](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/)

Comment: I don't know if and when it changed, but `ToString()` does not throw an exception (anymore): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.tostring?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 38):

You can simply use the `Convert.ToString()` which handles the null values as well and doesn't throw the exception

```
string str = Convert.ToString(a)
```

Or using `if` condition

```
if(a.HasValue)
{
  string str = a.Value.ToString();
}
```

Or using `?` Ternary operator

```
string str = a.HasValue ? a.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
```

Comment: And how does `Convert` handle `null`? Does it return "null" as OP asked?

Comment: This answer explains how to handle the exception for a `null` value.  Once you handle it then you can put your logic to get any value (e.g. "Null" from any of the options mentioned above.

Comment: to be clearer,`Convert.ToString(a)` returns `""` not `null`

Answer (score 4):

If you really need the string as "Null" if `a` is `null`:

```
string str = a.HasValue ? a.Value.ToString() : "Null";
```

Comment: this answer at least answers the question.

Answer (score 4):

The shortest answer is:

```
int? a = null;
string aString = a?.ToString() ?? "null";
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to create an extension method for this as I end up doing it over and over again

```
public static string ToStringNullSafe<T>(this T value)
{
  if(value == null)
  {
    return null;
  }
  else
  {
     return value.ToString();
  }
}
```

You can obviously create an overload with a format string if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

I'd create an extension method as well, but type it off of Nullable and not any T.

```
public static string ToStringOrEmpty<T>(this T? t) where T : struct
{
    return t.HasValue ? t.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
}

// usage
int? a = null;
long? b = 123;

Console.WriteLine(a.ToStringOrEmpty()); // prints nothing
Console.WriteLine(b.ToStringOrEmpty()); // prints "123"
```

Comment: Given the down votes people clearly don't like the extension method approach!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a.HasValue())
{
   return a.Value().ToString();
}
return string.Empty;
```