# Set int value in a string type textBox

Tags: c#

I want to get an 'int' value in a variable and set it in a textBox. The 2nd line of this code is showing an error:

> This expression cannot be used as an assignment target.

How can I solve it?

```
int nextCode = teacherManagerObj.GetCode();

//shows error "This expression cannot be used as an assignment target"
Convert.ToInt32(codeTextBox.Text) = nextCode;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int nextCode = teacherManagerObj.GetCode();
codeTextBox.Text = nextCode.ToString();
```

Comment: 'nextCode' is already an 'int' type. Then why convert it again in 'int'??? this code is not working bro.

Comment: @Ikr refresh the page. I was writing too fast. I changed my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to convert the `Text` property of `codeTextBox` to an Int32 and are trying to assign the Text property with an Int32, while it takes a string and you shouldn't try converting the `Text` property of TextBox to an Int32, since that isn't possible. You should try to convert the Int32 variable to a string and assign it to the `Text` property of `codeTextBox`.

Change

```
  int nextCode = teacherManagerObj.GetCode();
  Convert.ToInt32(codeTextBox.Text) = nextCode;
```

To:

```
codeTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(nextCode);
```

Or:

```
codeTextBox.Text = nextCode.ToString();
```

The difference between `Convert.ToString(nextCode);` and `nextCode.ToString()`, is that the first handles `null` values. The second one [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828154/difference-between-convert-tostring-and-tostring).