# Replace ().ToString() with Convert.ToString() in c# using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I was hoping to see if there is an easy way to Replace ().ToString() with Convert.ToString() throughout the application using Code Resharper or CodeRush or any other tool ?

Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that Convert.ToString() is also going to be significantly slower and won't allow you to do formatting.

Comment: Are you fortunate enough to be using the latest and greatest compiler everywhere? You should be able to replace `.ToString()` with `?.ToString()`. You may need a regular expression or some creativity to ensure that you don't accidentally replace `?.ToString()` with `??.ToString()`

Comment: One thing to note, if this is done for concatenation, you don't need `.ToString()` or `Convert.Tostring(...)`. This syntax: `var anything = (anything); string message = "The value is " + anything;` is valid for any type. `anything` can be a value type or class, and null is automatically converted to empty.

Answer (score 6):

`object.ToString()` does not equal `Convert.ToString()`.  The former will thrown an exception if `object` is null, so making the changes you suggested would be a breaking change because the application may handle the exception, for example.

See this post: [Difference between Convert.ToString() and .ToString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828154/difference-between-convert-tostring-and-tostring)

Comment: Thank you. My purpose is to convert the type to a string by avoiding null exceptions. Is there any way i can achieve this conversion using any tools like Code Rush, Resharper, etc ?

Comment: @JoeEnos Thank you..! That helped. I forgot about the null confitional operator.

Comment: @SuryaGarimella -- I think you meant to put that comment under your question where Joe Enos posted his comment, not under my answer.