# Difference between Convert.ToString(str) and str?.ToString() ?? ""

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

Is there any difference between these two approaches?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object str = null;

    string test1 = str?.ToString() ?? "";

    string test2 = Convert.ToString(str);
}
```

Edit 1:

As @Fabio pointed out, we have a third possible approach:

```
string test3 = $"{str}";
```

Comment: Another similar case, but without null coalescing operator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828154/difference-between-convert-tostring-and-tostring.

Comment: You can start reading from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/convert.cs#L1801) if you want to know the implementation specifics.

Comment: Here are two links from reference source: **[Convert.ToString(Object object)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,6a1a2c3ac58e60dd)** and **[Object.ToString()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,ff31a6bf27c58f89)**

Comment: Another approach: `var test3 = $"{str}"`

Comment: `var test3 = $"{str}"` will call `string.Format(str)` in the "background", which you can call explicitly as well ;)

Answer (score 3):

So, to answer your question directly: there is **no** difference between any of the approaches. There would be a difference in case of an `IFormatProvider` overload.

Now to dwelve into details:

`Convert.ToString` will try to call `IConvertible` and `IFormattable` interfaces (in that order) before falling back to base `object.ToString`. So if you pass something that does not implement any of these interfaces (or `null` on which you can't call any member methods), there will be no difference betweent this and a simple `object.ToString`.

Now string interpolation is a case of composite formatting (string interpolation is actually equivalent to calling `string.Format`). This one will call only the `IFormattable` interface implementation before falling back to `object.ToString`. Again, in case of something not implementing the interface (or a `null`), no difference.

To make things more complicated, both of these methods contain an overload that takes an `IFormatProvider` argument. In case of `Convert.ToString` the method will try to call `IConvertible.ToString(IFormatProvider)`, if the object implements the `IConvertible` interface. Then it tries the `IFormattable.ToString(String, IFormatProvider)` and if that fails it falls back to `object.ToString()`.

In case of composite formatting, it will try to call the `IFormatProvider.GetFormat` method and then use the returned `ICustomFormatter`. If that fails it continues to `IFormattable` and ultimately falls back to `object.ToString`.

When it comes to `null` values, there can be a difference when using the `IFormatProvider`. Since `Convert.ToString` tries to call the `IConvertible` implementation, and you can't really call anything on a `null`, it treats `null` as a special case and returns `string.Empty`. However, composite formatting calls the `ICustomFormatter.Format` with the object as an argument, so if you use an `ICustomFormatter` that handles `null` differently, you can get a different result! You can verify it with [this code snippet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QHv0Wa) (disclaimer: not the smartest way to implement an `IFormatProvider`, but it works as an example).

Here's [the MSDN doc for `Convert.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToString_System_Object_).

Here's [the MSDN doc for composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting) (see the Processing Order section).

Answer (score 0):

If we use Convert.ToString then it can handle the null values.But Tostring cannot handle null values

for example:

```
object str=null;
System.out.print(convert.ToString(str)); //shows null value
String s=str.ToString();
System.out.print(s); //throws exception
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert.ToString tries to use IFormattable and IConvertible interfaces before calling base Object.ToString
Example

```
class FormattableType : IFormattable
{
    private double value = 0.42;

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (formatProvider == null)
        {
            // ... using some IOC-containers
            // ... or using CultureInfo.CurrentCulture / Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
            formatProvider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        }

        // ... doing things with format
        return value.ToString(formatProvider);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Convert.ToString(new FormattableType()); // 0.42
new FormattableType().ToString();        // 0,42
```