# How to fix a problem with inserting data twice

Tags: c#

I have a code that upload files by an fileuploader, as well as a InsertCommand which inserts a data, belonging to that file.

That works fine, but if the string "maxId" has no result, he runs the button-code twice, upload the file twice and finally insert the data twice.

Any Ideas?
See my following code:

```
if (Bericht_Hochladen.HasFile)
{
    SqlCommand commandMaxActionDocID = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(actiondoc_id) FROM tbl_action WHERE SUBSTRING(actiondoc_nr, 2, 7) ='" + newNumber.Substring(newNumber.Length - 7) + "'", conn);
    string maxId = commandMaxActionDocID.ExecuteScalar().ToString();


    if (maxId == "")
    {
        neue_nr = newNumber.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", ci) + "_" + docart + "_DOC001";
    }
    else
    {
        SqlCommand commandMaxActionDocNR = new SqlCommand("SELECT actiondoc_nr FROM tbl_action_1100 WHERE actiondoc_id = @maxId", conn);
        commandMaxActionDocNR.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maxId", maxId.ToString());
        string NrMitT = commandMaxActionDocNR.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        string count_str = NrMitT.Substring(NrMitT.Length - 3, 3);
        int count_int = Int32.Parse(count_str);
        count_int = count_int + 1;
        count_str = count_int.ToString("000");

        neue_nr = newNumber.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", ci) + "_" + docart + "_DOC" + count_str;
    }

    string dateiendung = Path.GetExtension(Bericht_Hochladen.FileName);
    string todaydate = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    string dokumentname = neue_nr;


    #region [Datenupload WebDAV]
    Bericht_Hochladen.PostedFile.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/TemporaryUploadedFiles/") + dokumentname + dateiendung);

    SqlCommand commandVerweis = new SqlCommand("SELECT pfad_adresse FROM tbl_sys_pfad WHERE pfad_nr = 102", conn);
    string verweis = (string)commandVerweis.ExecuteScalar();


    //temporäreres Speichern auf dem WebServer
    FileStream fstream = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/TemporaryUploadedFiles/") + dokumentname + dateiendung, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);



    HttpWebRequest request_folder = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(filepath);
    request_folder.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(szUsername, szPassword);
    try
    {
        // Specify the MKCOL method.
        request_folder.Method = "MKCOL";
        HttpWebResponse response_folder = (HttpWebResponse)request_folder.GetResponse();
        Response.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }


    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(filepath + dokumentname + dateiendung);

    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(szUsername, szPassword);
    try
    {
        request.Method = @"PUT";
        request.ContentLength = fstream.Length;
        request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        request.SendChunked = false;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        Stream request_stream = request.GetRequestStream();

        byte[] indata = new byte[1024];
        int bytes_read = fstream.Read(indata, 0, indata.Length);
        while (bytes_read > 0)
        {
            request_stream.Write(indata, 0, indata.Length);
            bytes_read = fstream.Read(indata, 0, indata.Length);
        }
        fstream.Close();
        request_stream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK && response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Created)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Couldn't upload file");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    string del_URL = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/TemporaryUploadedFiles/") + dokumentname + dateiendung;
    File.Delete(del_URL);
    #endregion


    SqlCommand commandDocUpload = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_action(actiondoc_action_id, actiondoc_nr, actiondoc_art, actiondoc_pfad, actiondoc_datum, actiondoc_endung, actiondoc_bem, sys_crt_user, sys_crt_timestamp, sys_deleted) VALUES (@actiondoc_action_id, @actiondoc_nr, @actiondoc_art, @actiondoc_pfad, @actiondoc_datum, @actiondoc_endung, @actiondoc_bem, @sys_crt_user, @sys_crt_timestamp, @sys_deleted)", conn);
    commandDocUpload.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@actiondoc_action_id", (string)Session["action_id"].ToString()));
    commandDocUpload.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@actiondoc_nr", neue_nr.ToString()));
    commandDocUpload.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@actiondoc_art", Session["dokument_art_volltext"].ToString()));
    commandDocUpload.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@actiondoc_pfad", neue_nr.ToString() + dateiendung.ToString()));
    commandDocUpload.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@actiondoc_datum", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", ci)));
    commandDocUpload.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@actiondoc_endung", dateiendung.ToString()));
    commandDocUpload.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@actiondoc_bem", txtBeschreibungDoc.Text));
    commandDocUpload.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sys_crt_user", (string)Session["login"].ToString()));
    commandDocUpload.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sys_crt_timestamp", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", ci)));
    commandDocUpload.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sys_deleted", "0"));

    commandDocUpload.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();

    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        //Do Something
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing this line:

```
string maxId = commandMaxActionDocID.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

To this:

```
string maxId  = Convert.ToString(commandMaxActionDocID.ExecuteScalar());
```

And for reference:

[Difference between Convert.ToString() and .ToString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828154/difference-between-convert-tostring-and-tostring)

I think what's going on is that your ExecuteScalar() is returning something the if statement doesn't recognize, and therefore it's just skipping over it, and then once the data gets added, the value gets populated. Do you have the code that calls the method? That might be helpful.

EDIT:
David, Try changing your control to this:

```
<div class="pull-left btn-mybtn"> <asp:Button ID="btnDateiHochladen" runat="server" Text="Hochladen" CssClass="font-regular btn-mybtn pull-right"/> </div>
```

Also, does your code behind (C#) have an OnCommand or OnClick event for this particular button?

Comment: Thanks for answer, but unfortunately it seem´s not to be the reason for the problem, after I had already changed the code.

The code get called by a button click event:

```c#
<div class="pull-left btn-mybtn">
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnDateiHochladen" runat="server" Text="Hochladen" CssClass="font-regular btn-mybtn pull-right" OnCommand="btnDateiHochladen_Click"/>
                                        </div>```