# Different between ToString(),Convert.Tostring() and (string)variable in C#

Tags: c#

Different between **[ToString()]**,**[Convert.Tostring()]** and **[(string)variable]** in C#

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Convert.ToString() and .ToString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828154/difference-between-convert-tostring-and-tostring)

Comment: Convert.ToString() **CAN** handle null values and .ToString() will not.

Comment: `(string)3` will fail, while `3.ToString()` will work

Answer (score 1):

```
int A =0;
MessageBox.Show(A.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(A));
```

Here both the methods are used to convert the string but the basic difference between them is: "Convert" function handles NULLS, while "i.ToString()" does not it will throw a NULL reference exception error. So as good coding practice using "convert" is always safe. (string)casting is only to convert string and objects.

Let's see another example:

```
    string s;
    object o = null;
    s = o.ToString();
    //returns a null reference exception for s.

    string s;
    object o = null;
    s = Convert.ToString(o);
    //returns an empty string for s and does not throw an exception.

 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string s;
                object o = null;
                s = (string)o;
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }


            Console.ReadKey();  
        }
 //returns an empty string for s and does not throw an exception.
```

Comment: This is not the difference, this is just what they do in a particular circumstance, and its fairly suspect for the most part