# System.NullReferenceException Error Csharp

Tags: c#, sql, .net, nullpointerexception

Getting the error :

> System.NullReferenceException

for the below code on a C# Windows form.

```
try
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells["txtAttendance_Status"].Value.ToString() == "Attended")
        {
            row.Cells["txtStatus"].Value = true;
        }
        else if (row.Cells["txtAttendance_Status"].Value.ToString() == "Not Attended")
        {
            row.Cells["txtStatus"].Value = false;
        }
        else
        {
            row.Cells["txtStatus"].Value = false;
        }
    }
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error", ex.ToString());
}
```

Below is the table :

[image]

Comment: Include your full code as its not clear you are `inserting` or `getting` from database.

Comment: [ToString() vs Convert.ToSring()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828154/difference-between-convert-tostring-and-tostring)

Comment: Also include your full error to understand more on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Before running this line

```
row.Cells["txtAttendance_Status"].Value.ToString()
```

you have to check the content of row.Cells["txtAttendance_Status"].Value is not null.

You are performing a ToString() over a Null

EDIT: The code

```
switch (row.Cells["txtAttendance_Status"].Value)
{
    //only if its string with value Attended
    case string s when s.Equals("Attended", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase):
        row.Cells["txtStatus"].Value = true;
        break;
    default:
        //All other cases "Not Attended", null or whatever
        row.Cells["txtStatus"].Value = false;
}
```

Comment: somthing like if (row.Cells["txtAttendance_Status"].Value?.ToString() == "Attended")

Comment: It could be done in a single line with lambda and linq but its more readable this way

Answer (score 0):

```
try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)


                        if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells["txtAttendance_Status"].Value) == "Attended")
                        {
                            row.Cells["txtStatus"].Value = true;
                        }
                        else if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells["txtAttendance_Status"].Value) == "Not Attended")
                        {
                            row.Cells["txtStatus"].Value = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            row.Cells["txtStatus"].Value = false;
                        }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error", ex.ToString());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)


                    if (row.Cells["txtAttendance_Status"].Value.ToString() == "Attended")
                    {
                        row.Cells["txtStatus"].Value = true;
                    }
                    else if (row.Cells["txtAttendance_Status"].Value.ToString() == "Not Attended")
                    {
                        row.Cells["txtStatus"].Value = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row.Cells["txtStatus"].Value = false;
                    }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error", ex.ToString());
        }
```

In this code, If any database column having null value and you are trying to convert it as string, That time **System.NullReferenceException** is thrown.

For Example,
as per your SQL table result, for "requestid" 50 the "txtAttendance_Status" having a null value and the "System.NullReferenceException" error will occur if you try to convert this null value.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpGHZ.png)