# Difference in casting in the following 2 methods

Tags: c#, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [casting vs using the ‘as’ keyword in the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr)

hi,

can somebody please tell me what is the difference between the following two statements, because both of them give me the same results. Also i want to know which is better.

```
Label lblSome = e.Item.FindControl("lblMyLable") as Label;

&&

Label lblSome = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblMyLable");
```

thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as` checks if it can cast it, if it can't, it sets lblSome to null. Normal casting, `(Label)`, doesn't do that check for you, just gives you an `InvalidCastException` instead. However, `as` doesn't work with non-nullable structs.

Comment: "as only works with nullable objects, so you can't use as  with structs.": Nullables *are* structs. I think you mean you can't use it with non-nullable structs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if `e.Item.FindControl("lblMyLable")` returns an object that is not Label `(Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblMyLable")` will result in `InvalidCastException`.
while `e.Item.FindControl("lblMyLable") as Label` will result in null being assigned to lblSome.