# "(ListView)sender" versus "sender as ListView"

Tags: c#, casting, sender

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# “as” cast vs classic cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926677/c-sharp-as-cast-vs-classic-cast)

What is the difference between these two expressions?

- `(ListView)sender`
- `sender as ListView`

In General, I usually used the *exp* `sender as ListView`.
But in SO i find that most times users use `(ListView)sender`.

So, I want to know which one is more efficient.

Or,

If it is the choice of the coder, which one to use[and both works the same way]??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is that 
(ListView)sender will throw an exception if sender isn't a ListView, but sender as ListView will not throw an exception and return null instead if the cast is invalid.

Answer (score 5):

The difference would be that if for some reason sender was not castable to a ListView, `(ListView)sender` would throw an exception, while `sender as ListView` will cause the result to be null.

Answer (score 2):

```
var listview = (ListView)sender  // Throws an exception if sender is not listView
```

and

```
var listview = sender as ListView  // listview will be assigned to null if sender is not
                                   // a listview
```

Answer (score 0):

`as` operator doesn't throw an exception when it fails but instead fills the Left-Hand-Side variable with null.

While `(ListView)sender` will throw exception if sender is not ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Using `(a)b` will throw an exception if `b` is not assignable to `a` or cannot be converted, and can be used even when `a` is a non-nullable type (like `int`). Using `b as a` will never throw an exception (it returns `null` if `b` cannot be assigned to `a`), but will not convert (e.g. you can do `(int?)12.3` but not `12.3 as int?`) and will not work if `a` isn't nullable (e.g. you can do `12 as int?` but not `12 as int`).

Answer (score 0):

`sender as ListView` is the same as:

```
sender is ListView ? (ListView)sender : null
```

There is practically no difference in efficiency. `as` is safe against invalid casts since it produces a null result instead of throwing an exception, so I always use `as` and then check for the null condition.

Comment: I think the downside to this is that the IS will also do a cast which will result in a double cast

Comment: @TGH `is` performs a runtime check to see if it can complete a reference conversion without causing an exception. It doesn't actually perform the conversion. There are many such checks in the CLR as it is a managed environment, so I wouldn't worry about optimizing against it, or consider it a downside. `as` produces cleaner and safer code in most of the cases (I actually don't know of any cases where I would _choose_ to use a direct cast when I _could_ use `as`).

Comment: @ErenErsönmez I choose a direct cast when I *want* an exception to be raised in those "unfortunate situations". It's easier to understand an Invalid Cast Exception than a Null Reference Exception that occurs somewhere later on... if it's going to fail, fail fast.

Comment: @pst If I understand you correctly, you use it in cases where you _know_ a direct cast should work -- if it doesn't, then it's a bug, which you want to catch early in your tests. That is a reasonable choice.