# ASP.NET check if control on correct page

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference, custom-controls

i'm trying check if control(means user custom controls `*ascx` ) placed on correct page and i getting error - how to solve it

Control `Page_Load`:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddl.enable = (Page as Online.MyPage);
    }
```

Error:

```
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

But if we look on page life cycle it's possible:

```
  Page: PreInit
  Control: Init
  Page: Init
  Page: InitComplete
  Page: PreLoad
  Page: Load
  Control: Load
```

ThanX

**UDP:**

I think it can be some like this but i think it's a wrong way.

```
var v = Page as Online.MyPage;
if (v != null)
   ddl.enable = v;
```

**UPD:**

ddl.enable - means dropdownlist

```
 DropDownList ddList = new DropDownList();
 ddList.Enabled = y;
```

I dont want to delegate parent page right to operate control by property, just want to solve this across control.

Comment: There is not enough information. Based on your code, only reason you are seeing NullReferenceException is `Online is null`.

Comment: Ok but how to check it null or not if it's child control  - i have two different page with this control and i should show only on one of this page

Comment: A control shouldn't care on what page it's placed; use properties to control its behavior. You need to show the implementation of `ddl` and `ddl.enable` in order to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Page as Online.MyPage` will return null if Page cannot be casted to Online.MyPage. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4926702/2641278) for an explanation  on why.

What you want to be doing instead is to see if the type of the `Page` object inherits your custom `Online.MyPage` class. You can do this as such:

```
ddl.Enabled = Page.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Online.MyPage))
```

**Update:**

The given code example in the question is showing that ddl.enable is not a `bool` but some type of `object` instead. My assumption is that the intention is to enable or disable something based on the value of `ddl.enable` therefore I have assumed that `ddl.enable` is actually meant to be treated as a `bool` not an object. If `ddl.enable` is of type object, then the code will still compile since `bool` is also an `object`. Whether the code will execute without exception will entirely depend on what is done with `ddl.enable`.

Either case `Page.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Online.MyPage))` is probably the best way to detect if the control is on a particular type of page.

**Update 2:**

Now that `ddl` has been clarified as a `DropDownList` control, I have updated my code snippet so that it enables or disables the `DropDownList` control based on the Page type.

Comment: If the result of `Page as Online.MyPage` is `null` and `ddl.enable = null` throws an NRE, then the setter of `ddl.enable` contains code that accesses the reference. It's not a `bool`.

Comment: Yep, did see that but I have interpreted that question as the trying to enable/disable a control based on whether the `Page` inherits a particular class which doesn't necessarily make my answer wrong and is dependent on the @AleskP on showing the implementation of `ddl` and `ddl.enable` as you have asked.