# create session for IEnumerable<> list and reuse that session in controller methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, ienumerable, generic-list

I'm getting  `IEnumerable<object>` list to `Create_Brochure` controller method as follows

[image]

So I want to keep this object list and reuse in `Create_Brochure_PDF` controller method

So I added following lines to **create session** 
in `Create_Brochure` controller method

```
IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> newmodel = model;

Session["TemplateData"] = newmodel;
```

to Use that session in `Create_Brochure_PDF` controller method I added following lines to  `Create_Brochure_PDF` controller method

```
IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> newmodel = Session["TemplateData"] as IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM>;
```

but I'm getting `null` for this newmodel in `Create_Brochure_PDF` controller method

I need to know how can I define a Session for `IEnumerable<object>` list and reuse it in another method correctly.

Comment: Try like this `IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> newmodel =(IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM>)Session["TemplateData"];`

Comment: Same thing, except you can get an InvalidCastException if the cast fails rather than null.

Comment: @EricJ. Once I debug I can see its `null` not a cast issue i think

Comment: @kez: If your cast is invalid using the `as` syntax, the expression produces null.

Comment: @EricJ. getting this kind compile time error once I try your approach `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Cast<ProductsPropertiesVM>(IQueryable)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'`

Comment: Can you please edit your post and clarify if you are losing object altoghether (`Session["TemplateData"]` is null) or it has wrong type (show result of `Session["TemplateData"].GetType().FullName)` than)

Comment: @WaqarAhmed where should I replace that

Comment: Where you are casting the session back to `newmodel`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I cannot understand what you said here this is relevant code snippet https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/rLXR5

Comment: check  session timeout in web.config. or You can add it  <sessionState timeout="60"  /> in <system.web>.

Comment: @AnkushJain added like this but not working `<sessionState timeout="60" />
  </system.web>`

Comment: add debug point for both Create_Brochure_PDF() controller method and PrintIndex() and find out where its going to be null

Comment: What happens when you use `Session["TemplateData"] = newmodel.ToList();`, to store a real list in session instead of a Queryable that maybe needs a live database connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no problem of your definition ,

add your following line inside `PrintIndex()` , `Create_Brochure_PDF()` methods and add debug point for both `Create_Brochure_PDF()` controller method and `PrintIndex()` and find out where its going to be null

```
IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> newmodel = Session["TemplateData"] as IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM>;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this:**

```
IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> newmodel =(IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM>)Session["TemplateData"];
```

*Because* If your cast is invalid using the `as` syntax, the expression produces null.

[[Reference#1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr) [[Reference#2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926677/c-sharp-as-cast-vs-classic-cast)

Comment: So instead of returning null you recommend to produce exception... Not sure how it explains behavior OP observed.

Comment: @waqar once I use your approach getting also null this is the screenshot http://s17.postimg.org/x6ev5jg33/saadsa.jpg

Comment: @waqar I added your code line in `Create_Brochure_PDF` am I correct noh

Comment: Can you please post your complete code?

Comment: @WaqarAhmed here this is relevant code snippet https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/rLXR5