# What is the best way to convert Newtonsoft JSON's JToken to JArray?

Tags: c#, json.net

Given an array in the JSON, I am trying to find the best way to convert it to JArray.
For example - consider this below C# code:

```
var json = @"{
  ""cities"": [""London"", ""Paris"", ""New York""]
}";
```

I can read this JSON into JObject as -

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Now I will get the "cities" field.

```
var jsonCities = jsonObject["cities"];
```

Here I get jsonCities as type `JToken`.
I know `jsonCities` is an array, so  I would like to get it converted to `JArray`.
The way I do currently is like this -

```
var cities = JArray.FromObject(jsonCities);
```

I am trying to find out is there any better way to get it converted to JArray.
How are other folks using it?

Comment: You don't need to convert it to a `JArray` -- it already is a `JArray`.  You just need to cast it: `var jsonCities = jsonObject["cities"] as JArray`

Comment: I understand the question is subjective so there may not be one right answer, may be however I like this approach. I didn't realize that I can simply cast it. I am hopeful that this would be more performant than the one I have been using. Not sure if the performance concern deserves a separate question.

Answer (score 28):

The accepted answer should really be the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814603/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-newtonsoft-jsons-jtoken-to-jarray?rq=1#comment80577532_46814603) by [dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc).

After the proposed casting to JArray, we can validate the result by checking for null value:

```
var jsonCities = jsonObject["cities"] as JArray;
if (jsonCities == null) return;

...do your thing with JArray...
```

### Edit:

As stated by [dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc), a JToken that represent a JArray, is already a JArray.
That is if the JToken.Type equals an [JTokenType.Array](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenType.htm). If so it can be accessed by using the `as JArray` notation. When the `as` casting notation is used, a failed cast will render a `null` value, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4926702/3032543). That makes it convenient for validating that you actually got a JArray you can use.

`JArray.FromObject(x)` takes an `object`, so it can be used with anything that can be represented as an `object` and thus certainly an JToken.

In this case we know that we can simply cast from JToken to JArray, so it gives us another possibility. I would expect it to be faster, but I leave that as an exercise for someone else to figure out.

Answer (score -2):

Here we make use of c# classes to store the contents of our jsonString by deserialising the string.

Below is a basic example.

For Further Reading I will point you to the Newtonsoft.Json website.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var json = @"{""cities"": [""London"", ""Paris"", ""New York""]}";

        MyObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);

        foreach (var city in result.Cities)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(city);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("cities")]
        public List<string> Cities { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, the OP already is using Json.Net.  `JObject.Parse` is part of that library.  See [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) in the Json.Net documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have liberty to add a C# model class (MyObject above) in my case.