# Convert a UIElement to an Object?

Tags: c#, wpf, casting, livecharts

How would I go about converting a `UIElement` to a, in this problem, `CartesianChart` (LiveCharts).

In this code, I check for a Grid for a `CartesianChart` and then I *want* to store it (in `ch`).

```cs
            CartesianChart ch;

            for (int i = 0; i < Grid.Children.Count; i++)
            {
                var temp = Grid.Children[i].GetType();
                if (temp.Name == "CartesianChart")
                {
                    ch = Grid.Children[i];
                }
            }
            ch.Name = "Chart";
            ch.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 250, 125);
            ch.Series = new SeriesCollection
```

It says `are you missing a cast?`, but I'm unsure of how to cast a `UIElement` to an `Object`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [`as` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator)

```
 ch = Grid.Children[i] as CartesianChart;
```

or [*cast* operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#cast-operator-)

```
ch = (CartesianChart)Grid.Children[i];
```

The main difference between them is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926677/c-sharp-as-cast-vs-classic-cast)

I would recommend to use first approach. It can look like

```
 CartesianChart ch = null; // this lets avoid a compiler warning about using uninitialized vars
 for (int i = 0; i < Grid.Children.Count; i++)
 {
    ch = Grid.Children[i] as CartesianChart;
    if (ch != null)
    {
       break;
    }
 }
 if (ch != null)
 {
     ch.Name = "Chart";
     ch.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 250, 125);
     ch.Series = new SeriesCollection ...
 }
```

Please take into account, this code will find a first `CartesianChart` in the grid (if you can have several ones, you should perform additional checks).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Linq to traverse through the children of your grid, filter the requested type and choose the first one:

```
CartesianChart ch = Grid.Children.OfType<CartesianChart>().FirstOrDefault();
```

To be honest, your code traverses through all the children of your grid and assigns every `CartesianChart` to your variable. So after it finishes with the `for` loop, the last matching element found is stored in the variable.
If this is your desired behaviour, use this code:

```
CartesianChart ch = Grid.Children.OfType<CartesianChart>().LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: @Ethirix And this should of course be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Clemens The other does what I asked, this is just an extra fix.

On the side: I forgot (at the time) about handling if nothing was found.

Comment: @Ethirix - `FirstOrDefault()` and `LastOrDefault()` return null (default value) if the preceding `IEnumerable` is empty. So you simply wrap your following code in `if (ch != null) { ... }`. And if you want to perform the same actions for all `CartesianChart` elements, use LINQ's `.ForEach()` in the loop instead of `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @Mike Thanks for that note.