# Should I prefer the 'is' or 'as' operator?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [casting vs using the 'as' keyword in the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr)

```
foreach (MyClass i in x)
{
        if (i is IMy)
        {
                IMy a = (IMy)i;
                a.M1();
        }
}
```

or

```
foreach (MyClass i in x)
{
        IMy a = i as IMy;
        if (a != null)
        {
                a.M1();
        }

}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Second is more preferable as you cast 1 time

Comment: Yes, the second is preferred of the two given, but frankly there is a better third option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397311/should-i-prefer-the-is-or-as-operator/5397384#5397384

Comment: you can use the inline is keyword :
            foreach (MyClass i in x)
                if (i is IMy a) a.M1();

Answer (score 10):

I prefer a third option:

```
foreach(var i in x.OfType<IMy>()) {
    i.M1();
}
```

Comment: Whoa, that is pretty cool, short, and to the point.

Answer (score 8):

The second, as that only does one cast. Or you can use the `OfType` method:

```
foreach (IMy i in x.OfType<IMy>()) {
  i.M1();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Second is preferable, as you're casting only once.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) can also help understand this.  'as' operation does the 'is' check and returns either a casted object or a null - does all the work for you.

Answer (score 3):

The second. It's the same number of lines of code but you avoid doing the cast twice.

Note that whilst the second is preferable it wouldn't have worked it the type had been a value type. You can only use **as** on reference or nullable types.