# Casting with 'As' rather than (<T>)?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've been reading up on SharePoint 2010 for work and I've noticed that many code examples I run into from books to instructional videos are cast SharePoint objects in a way I never knew existed in C# (and thought was VB exclusive):

`SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;`

I'm so used to casting (outside of VB) this way `(SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent` and was just curious if there was any particular reason most pieces on SharePoint I've encountered use the VB-esque casting notation.

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with Sharepoint, you might want to re-tag. I added the C# tag.

Comment: Thanks, this is the only place I've ever seen it pop up so I thought it was just Best Practice for SharePoint.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr :)

Comment: You also need to be very careful with sharepoint IDisposable types. There are some cases where it returns you something that you should not dispose. So beware of "using" when coding against sharepoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) is called the safe cast operator in C#. There is a semantic difference between that and a normal cast. A safe cast will not throw an exception if the type cannot be cast; it will return null. A normal cast throws `InvalidCastException` if the type cannot be cast.

In other words, this code assigns `null` if Parent if not of type SPWeb:

```
SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
```

While the other version throws if Parent is not of the correct type:

```
SPWeb web = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;
```

The `as` operator can be quite useful if you don't know for sure that an object can be cast to the desired type - in this case it is common to use `as` and then check for null. `as` only works on reference types, since value types cannot be null.

This is also explained in [this longer article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx).

By the way, the equivalent operator in VB is `TryCast` (versus `DirectCast`).

Comment: Thanks, this seems like one of those obscurities that should be on the warning label!

Comment: It's also important to note that `as` is just syntax sugar.

Answer (score 2):

```
obj as T
```

is syntax sugar for

```
obj is T ? (T)obj : null
```

Thus, it is a "safe" cast.  However, it takes longer, in theory.  Thus, you should use normal casting unless you specifically want null if an object is not of the expected type.  More often, you are better off handling it manually:

```
if (!(obj is T))
{
    // Handle the case where obj is of an unexpected type.
}

T tobj = (T)obj;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the *as* keyword will set the variable **web** to null if the Parent is not of type SPWeb.

As where an explicit cast will throw an exception if the Parent is not of type SPWeb.

Answer (score 1):

"as" is safer than (cast) as it will either return a value as the given type or null.
You will find that the following line will (or should) test for null.

Answer (score 1):

If the cast fails the variable assigned to becomes null opposed to throwing an exception 'InvalidCastException '