# Which code is better: using "as" or "is"?

Tags: c#, syntax, casting, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Casting vs using the 'as' keyword in the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr)
>   [C#: “is” vs “as”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027946/c-is-vs-as)

This code:

```
    if (sheet.Models.Data is GroupDataModel)
    {
        GroupDataModel gdm = (GroupDataModel)sheet.Models.Data;
```

and this code:

```
    GroupDataModel gdm = sheet.Models.Data as GroupDataModel;
    if (gdm != null)
    {
```

Do you recommend any of the two styles above over the other one?

Comment: The first. The second may throw an exception if the casting is not possible

Comment: Define "better" - for what? Performance? Readability? Errors? Something else?

Comment: First one has the advantage of not introducing a possibly null symbol into your program

Comment: @AndreCalil - The type interrogation will prevent an InvalidCastException. However, a NullReferenceException *is* still possible in the first option, but not the second.

Comment: @KeithS: Both can throw `NullReferenceException` because `sheet` or `sheet.Models` could be null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its better to go for as because it convert as well as you can do check easily ..second one is good

More about this: [**Explicit and Implicit Casting of object and Role of 'is' and 'as' keyword in Explicit casting**](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2010/12/explicit-and-implicit-casting-of-object.html)

Difference between as and is

- as operator do conversion form one type to another type and return Null if converstion 
  fails. There is no need to conversion again if its convertible.
- is operator checks weather one object is convertible in another type or not and return false if not. So need to convert object to base type if it convertible.

Comment: The amount of effort needed to perform a cast is infinitesimal.  This is certainly a micro-optimization.  You should use the code that's more readable, or that otherwise logically makes more sense to you.  Performance shouldn't be a concern here.

Answer (score 5):

The latter is advocated by FxCop, as the cast only need be performed once (the `as`)

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, the two versions produce identical IL in this case:

**Code**:

```
void Main() {
    Class1 inst1 = new Class1();
    ((inst1 as Class1) != null).Dump();

    Class1 inst2 = new Class1();
    (inst2 is Class1).Dump();
}

class Class1 { }
```

**IL**:

```
IL_0001:  newobj      UserQuery+Class1..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     
IL_0008:  ldnull      
IL_0009:  ceq         
IL_000B:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000C:  ceq         
IL_000E:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump
IL_0013:  pop         
IL_0014:  newobj      UserQuery+Class1..ctor
IL_0019:  stloc.1     
IL_001A:  ldloc.1     
IL_001B:  ldnull      
IL_001C:  ceq         
IL_001E:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_001F:  ceq         
IL_0021:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump

Class1..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  ret
```

Comment: `is` is implemented in terms of `as` ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/16/is-is-as-or-is-as-is.aspx ). `((bar as Foo) != null)` is therefore obviously the same as `(bar is Foo)` which is what you're demonstrating

Answer (score 1):

The second version is preferred.

The second version only requires one type test. The first requires two type tests if the test succeeds (first for `is` and then again for the cast).

Comment: If the casting is not possible, won't it throw an exception?

Comment: @AndreCalil: Neither version throws an exception.

Comment: The first one could, depending on context. In a multithreaded situation `sheet.Models.Data` might be convertible to `GroupDataModel` at the time of the type check, but not at the time of the cast.

Comment: @SeanU: +1 That's a good point. The technical term to describe this is a "race condition".

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use the typed object afterwards use "`as`".

If you are not going to use the object with the type itself, use "`is`".

It is another concern if you EXPECT these objects to be of that particular type. Then just use cast and let it throw exception if type is not what you expect.