# Why does ReSharper recommend using "as" keyword instead of "is"?

Tags: c#, casting, operators

I using `Resharper` 8 and when I wrote

```
if (sender is Button)
```

`Resharper` reclaim to use `as` keyword and change it to:

```
Button button = sender as Button;
if (button != null)
```

There’s any particular reason?

are using `as` is real better then `is`? or in this case `as` is better?

Comment: I assume (i don't have resharper) that it's because you  want to use the `Button` later. The `as` casts it and checks whether or not it could be casted. The `is` just checks it, you have to cast it anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`as` is arguably better *if* the resulting expression is used later on; `is` is just as good if not. E.g.

```
if (sender is Button) {
    Button button = (Button)sender;  // just use `as`, as suggested
    button.Push();
```

(I thought ReSharper only gave a warning/hint in the case *where* a duplicate cast could be eliminated, such as this..)

That being said, I use the structure

```
Button button;
if ((button = sender as Button) != null) {
    button.Push();
```

to ensure that the variable is initialized in (and only starting in) the condition - this defers the application of `as` to the appropriate conditional expression and allows C#/ReSharper to detect some incorrect [uninitialized] variable usage cases.

---

See also:

[Casting vs using the 'as' keyword in the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr) - Jon's answer has 'is/(cast)' pairings as a "don't do" raising concerns with both shared and field vs. property access. Performance and 'is' vs 'as' differences are also discussed.

And a duplicate [Which code is better: using "as" or "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204132/which-code-is-better-using-as-or-is?lq=1), with some better related links.

Comment: Also note that in C# 6 we will be able to move the declaration of `Button`  inside the `if` itself, improving it still further: `if ((Button button = sender as Button) != null) {`

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because the `as` keyword does both, type check and cast at once. So if you later using the sender, you don't have to cast it

Comment: That pretty much is it - albei the JIT, or even the compiler, COULD optimize this.... it is not done to my knowledge, so he AS form saves one cast.

Answer (score 3):

The "as" operator is used to perform conversions between compatible types. Whereas the "is" operator is used to check whether the run-time type of an object is compatible with a given type or not.

So I think as would be a better option to go with as the as operator attempts to cast an object to a specific type, and returns null if it fails.

You can also check **Eric Liperts** blog on **[Is is as or is as is?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/16/is-is-as-or-is-as-is.aspx)**

> However, in practice the CLR provides us instruction isinst, which
>   ironically acts like as. Therefore we have an instruction which
>   implements the semantics of as pretty well, from which we can build an
>   implementation of is. In short, de jure is is is, and as is as is is,
>   but de facto is is as and as is isinst.

And **[What's the difference between "as" and "cast" operators?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/08/what-s-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators.aspx)**

From [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/532831/Use-of-Is-and-As-operators-in-Csharp):

> **Advantage of 'as' over 'is**
>
> In the case of is operator, to type cast, we need to do two steps:
>
> 1. Check the Type using is
> 2. If it’s true then Type cast
>
> Actually this affects the performance since each and every time the
>   CLR will walk the inheritance hierarchy, checking each base type
>   against the specified type. **To avoid this, use as it will do it in one
>   step.** Only for checking the type should we use the is operator.

Answer (score 0):

You did not post all your code. I guess in your code, if the sender is a button, you cast it to button and do something with it. If that's the case, you did that work *twice*, once in the if and once in the statement block. Resharper told you to do it once and be done with it.