# Difference between type cast and 'as' cast

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Casting vs using the ‘as’ keyword in the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr)

I know there are a lot of questions about casts but I don't know the specific names of these two casts so I'm not sure where to look. What are the differences between the two casts below?

```
TreeNode treeNode = (TreeNode)sender; // first cast
TreeNode treeNode = (sender as TreeNode); //second cast
```

Comment: The first is a "cast", the second is just the "as" operator (it is not literally a cast, it just contains a cast internally).  Since you mentioned not knowing the names.

Comment: You can read more here: [Safely Cast by Using as and is Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx)

Comment: Thanks now I know. I just didn't know the difference between a cast and the as operator that's why I had difficulty searching for the difference between these two

Comment: -1 and no comments explaining what's wrong about my question. Love it

Comment: I suspect the vote down is because of a question that can be answered by a quick google search of your question title

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first type of cast is called an "explicit cast" and the second cast is actually a conversion using the `as` operator, which is slightly different than a cast.

The explicit cast `(type)objectInstance` will throw an `InvalidCastException` if the object is not of the specified type.

```
// throws an exception if myObject is not of type MyTypeObject.
MyTypedObject mto = (MyTypedObject)myObject;
```

The `as` operator will not throw an exception if the object is not of the specified type. It will simply return `null`. If the object is of the specified type then the `as` operator will return a reference to the converted type. The typical pattern for using the `as` operator is:

```
// no exception thrown if myObject is not MyTypedObject
MyTypedObject mto = myObject as MyTypedObject; 
if (mto != null)
{
    // myObject was of type MyTypedObject, mto is a reference to the converted myObject
}
else
{
    // myObject was of not type MyTypedObject, mto is null
}
```

Take a look at the following MSDN references for more details about explicit casting and type conversion:

- [Casting (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)
- [Casting and Type Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)
- [How to: Safely Cast by Using as and is Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

If `sender` is not a `TreeNode` than the first one throws exception and second one returns `null`.