# converting vb DirectCast to c#

Tags: c#

i am converting a vb project to c#;
everything is ok except this line:

```
information = DirectCast(jsonserializer.Deserialize(jsonString, GetType(List(Of formData))), List(Of formData))
```

i created a class(formData) just same as vb, and json string is the same as vb.

```
    public class formData
{
    private string part;
    private string key;
    private string val;
    public formData(string part, string key, string val)
    {
        this.part = part;
        this.key = key;
        this.val = val;
    }

    public string Part
    {
        get { return part; }
        set { part = value; }
    }

    public string Key
    {
        get { return key; }
        set { key = value; }
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return val; }
        set { val = value; }
    }
}
```

what should i do?
i have to use "http://json.codeplex.com/"?

Comment: DirectCast can be translated to C# as a cast. That is: DirectCast(myOjbect, myType) in VB.NET equals (myType)myObject in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Directcast` in VB is the same as casting to type in C#.

So, I believe your code would look something like this:

```
var jsonserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var information = jsonserializer.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(List<formData>)) as List<formData>;
```

or

```
var jsonserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var information = (List<formData>)jsonserializer.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(List<formData>));
```

The difference between the two is that the former will return null if the cast fails whereas the latter will throw an exception.  There is a great discussion between casting as type and `as` on SO here:

[Difference between type cast and 'as' cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805617/difference-between-type-cast-and-as-cast)

Comment: It should be something like `information = (List<formData>)jsonserializer.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(List<formData>));`

Comment: Also the cast should never fail as the deserializer knows what type to deserialize to (I hope this sentence makes sense :-)

Comment: You have still to convert formData into List<formData> You are casting to formData and the original code casts to List<formData>

Comment: I did the editing myself to avoid misunderstandings (hope you don't mind but was a bug anyway so...)

Comment: thanks all: Erro The name 'jsonserializer' does not exist in the current context, i use : using System.Web.Script.Serialization; but i get this error. please help.

Comment: @mohammadadibi how are you declaring `jsonserializer` in VB?

Comment: Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Comment: [System.Web.Script.Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.aspx) doesnt have a property called jsonserializer.  This is a variable that you have declared.  How or where did you declare it in VB?

Comment: Just based on your comments i'm guessing that you want `JavaScriptSerializer`, i've edited the post.

Comment: yes you are right, that problem solved, but it doesn't work yet, let me check and inform you. thanks.

Comment: jsonString is a list of object, now i give this error: No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'ClearWhite.Classes.formData', would you helpme?

Comment: The constructor is your method called formData as you've listed above.  Notice that it accepts parameters.  A parameterless constructor is one that accepts no parameters. `public formData(){//do something here?}`

Comment: Check out [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386929/no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-type-of-system-string-during-json-des)

Comment: "[{\"part\":\"head\",\"key\":\"province\",\"val\":\"0\"},{\"part\":\"head\",\"key\":\"city\",\"val\":\"\"},{\"part\":\"head\",\"key\":\"selectedTab\",\"val\":\"1\"},{\"part\":\"controls\",\"key\":\"SELECT\",\"val\":\"1\"},{\"part\":\"controls\",\"key\":\"SELECT\",\"val\":\"4\"},{\"part\":\"controls\",\"key\":\"SELECT\",\"val\":\"10\"},{\"part\":\"controls\",\"key\":\"checkbox\",\"val\":\"18\"},{\"part\":\"controls\",\"key\":\"radio\",\"val\":\"22\"},{\"part\":\"controls\",\"key\":\"text\",\"val\":\"b b\"}]"

Comment: This is not a great forum for posting code.  Perhaps you should accept this answer and post another question.

Comment: above is my json and in my question i wrote class, i can't catch the error!

Comment: this is what i forgot to declare: JavaScriptSerializer jsonserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); everything must be ok.