# "Prefix" and "as" cast

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

This seems to be a very stupid question about casting, but...

I have the following setup:

There are a number of classes derivces from a main class. At some point in time and space I get an item, and want to handle it as object of subclass.

Asume:

```
class subClassA : mainclass 
class subClassB : mainclass
```

Now I have some if to ask which class it is:

```
if(someObject is subClassA)
{
    subClassA aA = someObject as subClassA ;
}
```

While for most subClasses the correct object is returned, I get for one subClass a `null`-Object.

If I do the following:

```
if(someObject is subClassA)
{
    subClassA aA = someObject as subClassA ; // <- aA = null; someObject is shown in debugger as object of subClassA

    object test = someObject as subClassA; // <- object is not null
    // or 
    subClassA aB = (subClassA)someObject; // <- object is not null, shows the correct object
}
```

I have results in `test` and `aB`.

What I do not understand:

Why does `as` fail and the prefix cast succeed?

---

Now I'm completly lost.

```
if(someObject is subClassA)
{
    subClassA aA = someObject as subClassA ; // <- aA = null; someObject is shown in debugger as object of subClassA

    subClassA aB = someObject as subClassA ; // <- aB != null.
}

if(someObject is subClassA)
{
    subClassA aB = someObject as subClassA ; // <- aB != null.
}
```

The name aA is localy defined. Only one thread accesses the method. If I just rename aA it works.

Comment: Are you certain `someObject` itself is not `null`?

Comment: The only thing I could think of is that this has to do with a confused type? Are you possibly casting from a type of the same name, but different assembly version?

Comment: -stanley I'm sure that someobject is not null - it shows entries and is cast correctly at later lines @pihony copied and pasted the type from the is to both other appearances. therefore all 3 ones should be the same. (that was the one i checked first). The funny thing is that i have used "as" as i have read that "as" should be up to 5 times faster.

Comment: I think the code can't work the way you describe. Could you include short but complete sample code that shows your problem (including definitions of all classes etc.)?

Comment: svick is correct; it should *never* be possible to have `if(x is Y) { Y y = x as Y; }` produce null for `y`. (Provided of course that x is not modified!) Please provide a small *complete* program that demonstrates what you're observing here.

Comment: @eric lippert: this happens in a 300k liner. The object comes from a OpenAccess query (getting a database object by an objectid, . the code really is in form if(null!=x){if(x is Y){Y y = x as Y;dosomestuffwithy();}else if(x is B){B b = x as B; dosomestuffwithb();}} if i go through the method step by step with a debugger i can see: 1a. x is not null. 1b. If x is Y it works as expected 2a. x is not null 2b. x is B is true 2c. B b = x as B; => b = null. (in debugger, x is still shown as B, and is shown to have values (like a database row ID).

Comment: Now the funny thing is: the object test above is shown as mainClass object after the cast, not as subClass'n' object

Comment: @Offler I agree with the others, something crucial is missing from your example: what are you describing it's not possible. If you cannot provide a complete example, can you at least do an ILDasm of the crucial lines there, and post it here?

Comment: @dema80 put a version of the working one (renamed variable) and not working one to it, but see no difference?

Comment: @Offler I think the key is here `stloc.s    V_4` VS. `stloc.s    aTargetPriceListItemDeliveryZone`. Are you using the same name for more variables? Do you have closures in the nearby code?

Comment: @dema80 the same name is used in the following way: ´if(a is A){ A variableName = a as A;} else if {a is B} { B variableName = a as B;}´ As far as i know the variable should only be accessable from within a block as stated in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx -> "The scope of a local variable declared in a local-variable-declaration (Section 8.5.1) is the block in which the declaration occurs." As far as I see no clusures in nearby code.

Comment: You said you're looking at this in the debugger. Are you debugging the *debug* version of the program or the *optimized* version of the program?

Comment: @ericlippert the build page is set to debug, is there any difference in debugger afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you are describing is confusing to say the least so could you try the following:

```
subClassA aA = (someObject as subClassA) ?? (subClassA)someObject;
```

Does that work (eg `aA` not null)?

You might want to refer to the following post for some details on `as`:

[Casting vs using the 'as' keyword in the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr)

Still investigating some more but I am not sure how to recreate the scenario...

EDIT:

Reading a lot from some very smart people ([Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) and [Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)) trying to find the answer...

See `is` documenation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=vs.110).aspx

`as` / conversion documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Comment: Your characterization of the relationship between is, as and cast is not quite right. See onemancat's answer, or my article here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/16/is-is-as-or-is-as-is.aspx

Comment: @EricLippert I thought so... the whole question had me pretty confused assuming the OP's scenario was correct which it seems it can be but not as simply as he has stated. I was trying to prove something that is not possible when I should have instead been trying to disprove the OP's scenario.  I have removed some of teh comments to not confuse the subject anymore than it already has :)

Comment: subClassA aA = (someObject as subClassA) ?? (subClassA)someObject; => returns an aA which is not null.

Comment: Okay. it is not working if i use the name of the original variable. The variable is created in the context, If I change the variable name also the normal "as" works.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), "as" is equivalent to:

```
expression is type ? (type)expression : (type)null
```

So, according to MSDN, in your code:

```
if(someObject is subClassA)
{
    subClassA aA = someObject as subClassA ;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if(someObject is subClassA)
{
    subClassA aA = someObject is subClassA ? (subClassA)someObject : (subClassA)null ;
}
```

Since `someObject is subClassA` appears on both lines, the only thing I could think would be either that 1) someObject is actually null in some case; or, 2) you have a multi-threaded application and your code is not thread-safe (i.e., from time to time the "is" line is true, but by the time the "as" line is reached, the implicit "is" has become false.)

Comment: You can't have “`null` but compatible with some type”. There is only one `null`.

Comment: 1) i go through the code step by step. the object someObject  is not null before the "as" cast, and someObject is not null after the cast. 2) for sure it is a multi-threaded application. But: a) why shoudl this happen only with one "as" cast and not with the others (and always with the one) b) in paralell task view I do not the any other thread using neither object nor method, the object is only build within one thread and accessed from it. c) the statement of kelsey "X a = (someObject as X) ?? (X)someObject;" shows the correct result.  (or the "(subClassA)" statement after the "as" statement.

Answer (score 0):

> While in most cases the correct object is returned, I get sometimes a null-Object.

There's only one simple explanation for your problem.  The *someObject* reference is being modified by another thread.  You'll need to use the *lock* statement to protect it.

Comment: the someObject is created within the thread which consumes it. Also if i look into the debugger i see no changes at the someobject. I meant with most cases: it is a form if(object is A){} else if(object is B){}else if(... most of the cases work, but only one tree "if(object is B)" does not work. In the case where it does not work i can get the correct object with the statement from kelsey's post (subClassA aA = (someObject as subClassA) ?? (subClassA)someObject;), but not with using "as"