# Owner Form in Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Lets say you have 2 forms: FormA and FormB..

In FormA I have some properties.
FormA creates FormB and set the owner property. for example:

```
public FormA() 
{
    FormB = new FormB(){Owner = this};
}
```

Now, in FormB if I want an access to the properties that I declared on FormA. 
why I can't see them when I'm Write:

```
Owner. // here I need to see FormA properties...
```

why it doesn't work like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't see because of inheritance and polymorphism.

Forms, in .NET, inherit from a base class called Form. You FormA is a class derived from Form, as is FormB.

Now, Form has a reference to an Owner form,

```
public Form Owner { get; }
```

You assigned a FormA to it. No problem! Derived classes can be treated as their base classes. But, if you access it, you get back a Form, so what you need to do is *cast* the new form back to the Form you actually provided:

```
FormA form = (FormB)Owner;
```

This is almost the same as doing:

```
FormA form = Owner as FormB;
```

But there are some caveats. The `as` operator is a "safe cast", which returns nulls if the object isn't of the provided type.

I'd recommend you just you the code we provided and, when you get the time, study Inheritance and Polymorphism. They are key to understanding what is happening.

If I may do some self-promotion, I [wrote a piece](http://blog.brunobrant.net/2011/08/careful-with-c-as-operator.html) on why you'd generally avoid `as` which you may find interesting, in time.

Comment: Jon Skeet covers `as vs cast` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/496167/119477). In the context of this question it depends of if Owner *should* be an instance for FormA or if it *might* be an instance of FormA. In the OP's example it looks like the *should* case but you'd need to know more about the application to know for sure.

Comment: @ConradFrix, I agree completely that it depends, and it was my opinion that the OP expected to have a FormA as the owner, since that was his problem in the first place. But I accept that it may not be the case.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
var forma = Owner as FormA;
forma.Stuff = otherstuff;
```

Comment: You might want to note somthing that this requires the scope of FormA.Stuff to not be private

Answer (score 3):

The reason is a concept called [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29).  In a more specific sense, the `Owner` property is of type `Form`.  `FormA` inherits from type `Form`, so in a way, it's a `Form` as well as a `FormA`.  The way you get around this is to "cast" owner as a `FormA`, as follows:

```
FormA fa = Owner as FormA;
if (fa != null)
{
    // do something
}
```

The reason you want to check for `null` here is that maybe someone else is using your `FormB`, and has set the `Owner` property to be of type `FormC`, which you won't necessarily be able to control.  In that case, the code `Owner as FormA` will return `null`.  The null check therefore ensures you don't get any nasty surprises.