# C# list of interface objects - casting single elements

Tags: c#, list, methods, interface, casting

I have a C# problem that has been bothering me for the past couple of days. I'll try to explain it based on an abstract description of what I am doing. Hope it is easy to follow. ;)

Let's say we have an interface

```
interface iFoo {
   void a();
}
```

Further I have for example 2 classes that implement this interface and the method that is in it:

```
class bar1 : iFoo
{
   public void a() { Console.WriteLine("bar1"); }
   public void anotherMethodBar1() { Console.Write("I love "); }
}

class bar2 : iFoo
{
   public void a() { Console.WriteLine("bar2"); }
   public void anotherMethodBar2() { Console.Write("beer"); }
}
```

Each class also provides an additional unique method - anotherMethodBar1() and anotherMethodBar2(). Now in my main() I want to create a list, which contains objects that implement my interface like this:

```
namespace ExampleFooBar
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<iFoo> fooBarObjects = new List<iFoo>();
            fooBarObjects.Add(new bar1());
            fooBarObjects.Add(new bar2());

            for(int i = 0; i < fooBarObjects.Count; i++)
            {
                if(fooBarObjects[i].GetType() == typeof(bar1))
                {
                    //Cast element to bar1 and use anotherMethodBar1()
                }
                if(fooBarObjects[i].GetType() == typeof(bar2))
                {
                    //Cast element to bar2 and use anotherMethodBar2()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I want to call each object's own (not included in the interface) method (based on the class we have anotherMethodBar1() or anotherMethodBar2(), which are NOT part of the interface). The question is - how do I do that? I'm new to C# and so far my experience had little to do with casting but right now I need it. Is this even done by using casting or is there another way? It is not possible to simply call the method

```
if(fooBarObjects[i].GetType() == typeof(bar1))
{
    fooBarObjects[i].anotherMethodBar1();
}
```

because C# doesn't understand the exact type that lies underneath and thus the available methods/functions for this object are only the standard once plus my a()-method:

- a()
- Equals()
- GetType()
- GetHashCode()
- ToString()

I really tried to find a solution but so far only the inverse has been asked quite often - list of objects to a list of interface conversion.

Thanks a lot and best regards!

Comment: Actually you gave the answer in your comments "Cast element to bar1 and use the anotherMethodBar1". `((bar1)fooBarObjects[i]).anotherMethodBar1();`

Comment: I would recommend you to read this answer: [Casting vs using the 'as' keyword in the CLR](http://stackoverflow.com/a/496167/1730086).

Comment: Thanks, guys! Really fast and helpful. Knaģis is the best answer omho, so I marked it as such. The "is" and "as" keywords are the keys to the solution. I tried casting many times as Mehmet Ataş suggested, but the result is as described at the end of my question. This was bothering me because I really didn't understand why it was happening. Using "is" resolves the problem and works like a charm.

Comment: There's a separate question here around why you have a list of interfaces, i.e. the *commonality* between objects, when what you're interested in is their *differences*. Often, resorting to run-time testing of an object's type in a statically-typed language indicates a problem with the design which could be solved better (more elegantly and without missing corner cases) using polymorphism.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
        for(int i = 0; i < fooBarObjects.Count; i++)
        {
            if(fooBarObjects[i] is bar1)
            {
                ((bar1)fooBarObjects[i]).anotherMethodBar1();
            }
            else if (fooBarObjects[i] is bar2)
            {
                ((bar2)fooBarObjects[i]).anotherMethodBar2();
            }
        }
```

The key is the keyword `is` which checks if the object is of type `bar1` (or any type derived from `bar1`) and the `(type)object` syntax which casts the object to your specified type.

An alternative option is to use `as` keyword which does the cast and returns `null` if the cast cannot be done.

```
        for(int i = 0; i < fooBarObjects.Count; i++)
        {
            var b1 = fooBarObjects[i] as bar1;
            if  (b1 != null)
            {
                b1.anotherMethodBar1();
            }
            else
            {
                var b2 = fooBarObjects[i] as bar2;
                if (b2 != null)
                {
                    b2.anotherMethodBar2();
                }
            }
        }
```

The second option is considered to be recommended over the first because the runtime only has to do the type checking once (in the `as` keyword) instead of twice (`is` and `()`).

Comment: It's better in this case to use `as` and then compare the result to null to see if it can be used. You are using `is` and then casting which will check the type twice; using `as` will only check the type once.

Comment: It's better to use polymorphism and eliminate any testing at all.

Comment: Matthew Watson, great tip.
spender, yes it is also possible to use polymorphism but in my (real) case I find it easier to use interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`as` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to try-cast it to the type:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fooBarObjects.Count; i++)
{
    var bar1 = fooBarObjects[i] as Bar1;
    if (bar1 != null)
        bar1.anotherMethodBar1();
    else {
        var bar2 = fooBarObjects[i] as Bar2;
        if (bar2 != null)
            bar2.anotherMethodBar2();
    }
}
```

This is the most readable and less error-prone way to cast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension method to extract items of a certain type:

```
var allTheBar1s = fooBarObjects.OfType<bar1>();
foreach(bar1 item in allTheBar1s)
{
    //bar1 action
}
//...etc...
```

Of course this requires a second iteration for the `bar2` items, but unless this is a hotspot, this doesn't really matter.

Perhaps preferable would be to use polymorphism and a single interface method to apply the action. This avoids any kind of requirement to test types.

```
interface IFoo
{
    void DoSomething();
    ...
}
class bar1 : IFoo
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
         this.anotherMethodBar1();
    }
    ....
}
class bar2 : IFoo
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
         this.anotherMethodBar2();
    }
    ....
}
```

Now:

```
foreach(IFoo item in fooBarItems)
{
    item.DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply cast it :)

```
(fooBarObjects[i] as bar1).anotherMethodBar1();
```

Picking what you had

```
for(int i = 0; i < fooBarObjects.Count; i++)
{
   if(fooBarObjects[i].GetType() == typeof(bar1))
      (fooBarObjects[i] as bar1).anotherMethodBar1();
}
```

Comment: Bang. NullReferenceException when an item isn't a `bar1`

Comment: @user2285800: Don't forget to check for null