# Type Cast Operator Precedence

Tags: c#

I ran into a scenario today while implementing search functionality in my application that has left me puzzled. Check out this snippet:

```
public string GetFirstProductName(SortedList<string, object> itemsList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < itemsList.Values.Count; i++) {
        if (itemsList.Values[i] is Product)
           // Doesn't Compile:
           // return (Product)itemsList.Values[i].ProductName;

           // Does compile. Precedence for the "." higher than the cast?
           return ((Product)itemsList.Values[i]).ProductName;
        }
    }
}
```

So, what is the precedence for the cast? Is a cast an operator? What about the `as` keyword - is that an operator and what is its precedence?

Comment: There's an order of precedence table at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its quite simple really.

When you don't wrap the cast in brackets.. you're casting the entire expression:

```
return (Product)itemsList.Values[i].ProductName;
//              |______________________________|
```

You're essentially casting a `string` to a `Product`. Whereas:

```
return ((Product)itemsList.Values[i]).ProductName;
//     |____________________________|
```

Casts just that part, allowing the `.` to access the properties of a `Product`. Hopefully the bars help show you the difference more clearly.

Comment: That's a wonderful explanation your made there. +1 for the visual implementation.

Comment: "When you don't wrap the cast in brackets.. you're casting the entire expression" is true *for this specific example*, because the "." is a Primary operator and has the highest level of precedence while the (T)x operator is Unary and is second-highest. It is not necessarily true for all expressions!

Answer (score 4):

`x.y` has a higher precedence than the cast:

**7.3.1 Operator precedence and associativity**

> The following table summarizes all operators in order of precedence
>   from highest to lowest:
>
> Primary x.y  f(x)  a[x]  x++  x--  new typeof  default  checked 
>   unchecked  delegate
>
> Unary  +  -  !  ~  ++x  --x  (T)x

Answer (score 1):

It is not about precedence. Always value is converted

```
// Does compile. Precedence for the "." higher than the cast?
 return ((Product)itemsList.Values[i]).ProductName;
```

in your case value is being returned by `itemsList.Values[i]` which is being casted into Product. Then you are trying to access ProductName from it.

[CAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) is an Operator

`Is/as` works only on reference types

```
 return (itemsList.Values[i] as Product).ProductName;
```

[READ MORE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr) to understand `difference between CAST and AS`

Answer (score 1):

`(Product)itemsList.Values[i].ProductName;` means `(Product)(itemsList.Values[i].ProductName);` whereas second line you explicitly say to cast `Values[i]` and then do `.ProductName`;