# Runtime Type casting without generics

Tags: c#

This code works. But noticing the similarity between the 6th & 10th line,

```
void someThing_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    President pres;                
    if (e.GetType() == typeof(MouseButtonEventArgs))
    {
         pres = (sender as SomeUserControl ).DataContext as President;
    }
    else
    {
         pres = (sender as MenuItem ).DataContext as President;
    }
}
```

is there a way to shorten the code like,

```
Type t = (e.GetType() == typeof(MouseButtonEventArgs)) ? SomeUserControl : MenuItem;
pres = (sender as t).DataContext as President;
```

the code above doesn't work, just for illustration.

Comment: Use "as" operator only if you will check the result of it. In other cases, you should use normal cast (Type) operator - it has better performance.

Comment: "normal"(direct) cast isn't faster, internally it uses combination of [is] and [as] operators. please have a look at my comment to @xxMUROxx answer

Answer (score 4):

I think no need of checking type of event args and all, this should be enough

```
President pres = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as President;
```

Answer (score 2):

DataContext property is of class `FrameworkElement` i.e. your `SomeUserControl` and `MenuItem`  inherit from `FrameworkElement`. So you can type cast it to `FrameworkElement` directly:

```
pres = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as President;
```

Comment: This is semantically different from OP's code, you missed else part; though if block itself completely redundant

Comment: No need for if I guess, he get President for both cases

Comment: @Sriram - I hope the intent was clear from the description. Any ways remove the else part.

Comment: Rohit, that's clear indeed but when you use `if` without else semantics of the code will be changed if `e` is not of type `MouseButtonEventArgs`. That's my point.

Answer (score 2):

Directly use `DataContext` from `FrameworkElement`

```
var fe = sender as FrameworkElement
if(fe != null)
{
    President pres = fe.DataContext as President;
}
```

Comment: Combination of [as] and comparison with null is the most effective way of doing certain type job with untyped object.(direct cast first checks with [is] and then either throws exception or returns object casted with the use of [as] operator, that is one extra [is] operation)

Comment: @Andrew Point 1 agreed, but I disagree that `direct cast first checks with [is] and then either throws exception or returns object casted with the use of [as] operator, that is one extra [is] operation` can you show a official documentation for this? Or any provable link?

Comment: for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr direct cast is internally translated to `if (variable is T){ return (variable as T)} throw.... `

Comment: I did some maths(kind of load test) in the past...try doing the same: a million of direct cast operations versus million of [is]-[as] combinations

Comment: another good one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8052/Type-casting-impact-over-execution-performance-in