# Is it possible to pass a reference to a generic object casted into a different type?

Tags: c#

I have a method that I'd want to accept ref to a specific object:

```
    public static void Death(ref Animal unit)
{
...
}
```

And then i have :

```
object target
```

A generic object that can be a Animal and other stuff.
If it's an Animal I want to cast target into Animal and then pass that ref to my Death method but I can't figure out how to do it...

Answer (score 1):

```
Animal a = target as Animal;
if(a != null)
{
    Death(ref a);
}
```

EDIT: If you want to modify `target` in `Death`, the only way is to do the check in there:

```
public static void Death(ref object unit)
{
    Animal a = unit as Animal;
    if(a != null)
    {
        //assign unit
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this syntax is correct but the effect doesnt work, i already tried it but the death method doesnt affect the real target

Comment: @user3161621 "doesn't affect"? Is `Animal` by any chance a `struct`?

Comment: @dcastro I mean OP says it doesn't affect target but it would have affected `a`

Comment: Oh, you mean assigning something new to `a`. I thought you meant mutating the instance's state, which could only be explained by the unboxing of `target` into `a`.

Comment: @user3161621 - If you want to update `target` you'll have to pass it directly by changing the parameter type.

Comment: @AmitJoki - Your answer is effectively identical to my original.

Comment: @Lee, oh, yeah, except that mine is more robust, doesn't check for nulls

Comment: @AmitJoki - Yours isn't more robust at all, it just does the check twice.

Comment: @Lee, twice? how. Maybe implicitly

Comment: @AmitJoki - `is` and `as` are both dynamic type checks, so your answer does two while this only does one.

Comment: @AmitJoki `as` followed by null check is always better than `is` followed by `as` or `is` followed by direct cast.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, I would like to know why?

Comment: @AmitJoki - The cast still requires a dynamic type check, although the `is` check before means it will not throw any exceptions. `as` already guarantees it does not throw, so is usually preferred.

Comment: @AmitJoki [Does this answers your question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr/496167#496167)

Comment: @Lee, yeah now I understood. So, it returns null if it isn't of type `Animal`

Comment: Guys, deleted my answer, when I got to know Jon Skeet said "Don't do this".

Comment: ok last question maybe i found the last problem:

would unit = null; work inside my Death method?

apparently all the Animal methods i use work on the ref but then when i try to "delete" it this doesnt work

Comment: @user3161621 - If you set `unit` to `null` inside `Death` then it will affect the ref variable in the caller. I'm not sure what you mean by "delete" though. If you have a collection of animals you can just remove the dead one from the collection and wait for it to be garbage collected if there are not more references.

Comment: yes but i would want to do it without accessing the collection (but yeah, now i think i lost enough time on this matter and ill do it like that) so i wondered if there was a sort of self destruction 

anyway i still dont get why in my death method unit.mymethod work on the real collection referenced while unit = null doesnt...

Comment: @user3161621 - There is a difference between a reference type variable and passing by reference, which you are doing here using `ref`. Copies of a reference type variable all point to the same object in memory and so can call `MyMethod` to modify it. Passing a variable by reference means that the variable in the method is an alias for the variable in the caller, so assignments to the local variable are visible in the caller.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean changing the ref parameter doesn't affect `target` you can update manually like this.

```
Animal animal = target as Animal;
if(animal != null)
{
    Death(ref animal);
    target = animal;//Update it manually to target
}
```

Comment: would you mind me asking what mistake is there in my code now?

Comment: oh well this seems to be a good workaround after all, there is still a problem in my code but its unrelated (i think)

but isnt there a more elegant way to do all this?

Comment: Basically no, because you don't have a `target` type as `Animal` so I believe there will not be any more elegant way :( If you find any pls let us know..