# C# casting how these two ways are different

Tags: c#, type-conversion

In C# What's the difference in casting if I do

```
MyType  mytype = (MyType) obj;
```

Or

```
MyType  mytype = obj as MyType;
```

Comment: [Here is the same question with an excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr)

Answer (score 1):

The first methods fails when `obj` cannot be converted into `MyType`. When you use the second way then `mytype` is either`obj` casted into `MyType` or it is null if it cannot be casted.

Answer (score 0):

The second one can only be used with reference types (classes and interfaces) and will return null if the variable is not of the cast type.
The first works with any types (structs as well) and will instead throw an exception.