# how to set backcolor for all textboxes in winform globally C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

how to set back color for all text boxes in win form globally?
can we set it somewhere like in a global variable and use when needed?
I need to set the back color of control in form_load from a global variable instead of writing

```
mytextbox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
mytextbox2.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Have you tried below answer?

Comment: yes it works fine. i want to use this method  in all forms, how to access this method globally?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check

Comment: public class Helper  
    {
        public void SetRedColorToTextBoxes(Form frm) --> Form could not be found(are you ....
        {
            Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null; --> control could not be found(are you ....

            func = (controls) =>
            {
                foreach (Control control in controls)
                    if (control is TextBox)
                        (control as TextBox).BackColor = Color.Red;
                    else
                        func(control.Controls);
            };

            func(frm.Controls);
        }
    }

Comment: add two namespace `using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;`

Comment: it works well. thanks a lot Arshad

Comment: we can assign the backcolor of controls without using this. what is the advantage of using action delegate?

Comment: if i want to access this 'SetRedColorToTextBoxes' method from Helper class, i can create the object of Helper class and i can acess it. Here you've written '(new Helper()).SetRedColorToTextBoxes(this);' does it means same as creating object and accessing the method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 private void SetRedColorToTextBoxes()
 {
     Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;

     func = (controls) =>
         {
             foreach (Control control in controls)
                 if (control is TextBox)
                     (control as TextBox).BackColor = Color.Red;
                 else
                     func(control.Controls);
         };

     func(Controls);
 }
```

and call `SetRedColorToTextBoxes()` function in form load.

```
    private void YourForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetRedColorToTextBoxes();
    }
```

**Edit**
Add a .cs file and put the code there.

```
  class Helper
   {
    public void SetRedColorToTextBoxes(Form frm)
    {
        Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;

        func = (controls) =>
        {
            foreach (Control control in controls)
                if (control is TextBox)
                    (control as TextBox).BackColor = Color.Red;
                else
                    func(control.Controls);
        };

        func(frm.Controls);
    }
}
```

and call it your form load as :

```
 private void YourForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this means instance of  currentform.
       (new Helper()).SetRedColorToTextBoxes(this);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, it works fine. but to call this method in another form i need to write this method again.could you please tell me a solution for this.I need to access this same method globally.

Comment: @Prathapsv: Simply make this method `static` within some (maybe) static helper class and provide all parameters within the method call.

Comment: @Arshad: If you have to test an object to be of a specific type and afterwards need to use it as this type you should not double type check it. Either you write `if(control is TextBox) ((TextBox)control).BackColor = Color.Red;` or (what i would prefer in this case) `var textBox = control as TextBox; if(textBox != null) textBox.BackColor = Color.Red;`. Also take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr).

Answer (score 0):

Can i make sure you are not looking for themes. Some third parties like devexpress gives option to design your own themes

Answer (score 0):

As a slight change to Arshad's solution above, I would also make the method to take colour on the fly:

```
public void SetRedColorToTextBoxes(Form frm, Color myColor)
```