# What is the difference between these two casting methods?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Inside a class, I have an enum and a private int:

```
 public enum DOOR_STATE { IDLE = 0, OPENING, OPEN, CLOSING };
 private int currentState;
```

Inside a method, if I do:

```
currentState = DOOR_STATE.OPENING as int;
```

I get an error message: "The as operator cannot be used with a non-nullable value type int"

But if instead I do:

```
currentState = (int) DOOR_STATE.OPENING;
```

The error goes away.

Could someone please explain the difference between the two casting methods ?

Comment: [as](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx): "if the conversion isn't possible, **as** returns **null** instead of raising an exception" - since `int`s can never be null, that's why you can't use it.

Comment: There are already various questions like this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr