# Spawn after throw

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a football game project. I want a sphere I have to spawn another sphere after I throw the 1st sphere. Here's something I tried:

```
public class spawn : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform[] SpawnPoints;
    public float SpawnTime;
    public GameObject ball;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        InvokeRepeating ("SpawnBalls", SpawnTime, SpawnTime);
    }

    void SpawnBalls(){
        if (transform.position.z > -0.904 ) {
            int SpawnIndex = Random.Range (0, SpawnPoints.Length);
            Instantiate (ball, SpawnPoints [SpawnIndex].position, SpawnPoints [SpawnIndex].rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem here? What doesn't works?

Comment: ... and your question is...?

Comment: Its working,but not the way I want.I want the Sphere to spwan only after I throw the first sphere,but my code spwaing the sphere after some time period.

Comment: I want my object to spwan after I throw the 1st object in the air@amy

Answer (score 3):

Simply instantiate a new ball if the last ball thrown is far enough. Try this:

```
public class spawn : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform[] SpawnPoints;
    public GameObject ball;
    public GameObject lastBall;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        int SpawnIndex = Random.Range (0, SpawnPoints.Length);
        lastBall = Instantiate (ball, SpawnPoints [SpawnIndex].position, SpawnPoints [SpawnIndex].rotation) as GameObject;
    }

    void Update(){
        if (lastBall.position.z > -0.904 ) {
            int SpawnIndex = Random.Range (0, SpawnPoints.Length);
            lastBall = Instantiate (ball, SpawnPoints [SpawnIndex].position, SpawnPoints [SpawnIndex].rotation) as GameObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,but I am getting an error,it's saying "An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: @alterego Replace `lastBall = Instantiate (ball, SpawnPoints [SpawnIndex].position, SpawnPoints [SpawnIndex].rotation);` **with** `lastBall = Instantiate (ball, SpawnPoints [SpawnIndex].position, SpawnPoints [SpawnIndex].rotation) as GameObject;`

Comment: @alterego Does the edit suggested by programmer solve your issue?

Comment: Its just respawing too many object at a time after I hit play.

Comment: On line 14, is it best practice/more efficient to do `as GameObject` like you are doing there or cast to GameObject with `(GameObject)` at the beginning of the line? That might fix @alterego 's problem of "An explicit conversion exists"

Comment: @yummypasta The only difference between the two are `as GameObject` will return `null` if the cast is impossible and casting with`(GameObject)` will throw an exception instead. See: [Casting vs using the 'as' keyword in the CLR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr)