# C# Access inherited class properties from list of base class

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

First, I create base class and inherited class

```
public class Entity
{
   public int EntityID;
   public EntityType type = EntityType.NONE;
}

public class EntityObject : Entity
{
   public Vector2 position;
   public EntityObject()
   {
      position = Vector2.Zero;
      type = EntityType.OBJECT;
   }
}
```

And then I create list of base class to store all inherited class

```
List<Entity> entityList = new List<Entity>();
entityList.Add(new EntityObject());
```

Later, I try to access a member of inherited class in list

```
for(int i = 0; i < entityList.Count; i++)
    if(entityList[i].type == EntityType.OBJECT)
        entityList[i].position = Vector2.One;
```

Yeah, I got an error : 'Entity' does not contain a definition for 'position'and no extension method 'position' accepting a first argument of type 'Entity' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is there a probably way to access inherited class properties from list of base class?

Comment: A separate consideration is your use of the relatively heavyweight `List` class when you only require an `IEnumerable` implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast the `Entity` instance to an `EntityObject` instance, because the `Position` field is indeed not part of `Entity`

So:

```
var entityObjectInEntityList = (EntityObject)entityList[0]
```

Will give you the correct type, which you can then access the `.Position` field against.

---

As mentioned in the comments, you could also test the type / do the cast the following ways:

```
if(entityList[0] is EntityObject)
```

> Just testing type - usually avoided as you still need to cast to get the correct type and that involves overhead

```
var item = entityList[0] as EntityObject;
if (item != null)
{
   var position = item.Position;
}
```

OR with C# 6

```
var position = (entityList[0] as EntityObject)?.Position;
```

> Using the `as` keyword to perform a cast, and return a null if it fails.

---

In the interests of mercy, as pointed out by Henk, you're clearly trying to include some type information in your class, in the form of the `EntityType` property.

You can determine the type of an object at runtime:

```
var type = instance.GetType();
```

Therefore:

```
if(itemInList.GetType() == typeof(EntityObject))
```

will tell you the type of the instance, but using things like type checking of derived classes is often a smell.

Assuming you don't need any base functionality on `Entity` I would recommend going with an interface approach instead.

I'd recommend looking here: [Interface vs Base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class)

Comment: Come on, also replace the DIY type system.

Comment: Better than an explicit cast, would be use of the `as` keyword combined with a null check. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr

Comment: Yes, I wasn't thinking of GetType() either. Several solutions exist with `is` and  `as`.

Comment: I try to avoid GetType and the as / is at all costs as a general rule, much more a fan of using a decent interface structure and just expecting the interfaces that conform to the functionality I'm after at the call site.

Comment: thank you for all solutions and comment, now I can continue working. much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've declared your list as `List<Entity>`, but you are trying to use it as `List<EntityObject>`.

**I think in your case you should declare your list as List< EntityObject>.**

The other way is to cast your element as EntityObject like this:

```js
((EntityObject )entityList[i]).position = Vector2.One;
```

What way you take depends on your bussiness model, your preference, semantic and your propose. In this case the question would be:

- **Why did you define your list as `List<Entity>` and then you manage it as `List<Entitybject>`?**

Comment: Because there are various inherited class to store in list, that's why I declare as List<Entity>

Comment: Perfect, in that case you must cast them. But you might want to make clearer splitting into methods.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Facundo La Rocca (below), you have to cast the object to the type you want to work with before you access its properties.  However, if you are going to add multiple different EntityTypes (Object, Character, etc.) then you can still leave it as a base List of Entity.  You just have to make sure that for each different type of Entity in your list, you check (and cast) to which one it is:

```
public static void Main(string[] args){
    var entityList = new List<Entity>();
    entityList.Add(new EntityObject()); 

    for(int i = 0; i < entityList.Count; i++) {
        if(entityList[i] is EntityObject)
            ((EntityObject)entityList[i]).position = Vector2.One;
        else if (entityList[i] is EntityCharacter)
            ((EntityCharacter)entityList[i].characterProperty = someValueToSet;
    }
```