# Make instance of "object" to other class and call method

Tags: c#, instance

I want to define an `object` and make instance of it to other class, but I can't call the method, here's my code:

```
    class Test1
    {
        public bool True_1()
        {return true;}
    }

    class Test2
    {
        public bool True_2()
        {return true;}
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            object a;
            bool flag = true; // or false


            if (flag)
                a = new Test1();
            else
                a = new Test2();


            if (a is Test1)
                a.True_1();        //error before compiling
            else
                a.True_2();        //error before compiling
        }
    }
}
```

I know there's a way of creat an interface `I_Test`, and do this:

```
class Test1:I_Test 
class Test2:I_Test
```

but since class `Test2` is a dll from third-party so I can't add `:I_Test` to it,
so I want to make my code here achievable, any suggestion? thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast it first

```
if(a is Test1 aConverted) 
    aConverted.True_1();
```

Or older way of doing this:

```
if(a is Test1) 
    ((Test1)a).True_1();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the C# 7 you can use the new syntax that allows you to test and put the result of the test into a variable in a single line :

```
if (a is Test1 aTest)
    aTest.True_1();
else if( a is Test2 aTest2)
    aTest2.True_2();
```

If you are using older C# you can use the `as` operator coupled with a null test :

```
var aTest = a as Test1;
if (aTest != null)
    aTest.True_1();
else
{
    var aTest2 = a as Test2;
    if (aTest2 != null)
    {
        aTest2.True_2();
    }
}
```

You can also use a test and cast solution which minimizes the amount of variables, this is not recommended as that may forces the runtime to test twice (once for `is` and once for the cast). See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr) for a more detailed response

```
if(a is Test1) 
    ((Test1)a).True_1();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do these two solutions to solve this problem:
1. Convert `a` to the class that you want and then you can call the method: Try this:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        object a;
        bool flag = true;


        if (flag)
            a = new Test1();
        else
            a = new Test2();


        if (a is Test1)
        {
            ((Test1)a).True_1();        //So, there will be no error anymore
        }

        else
        {
            ((Test2)a).True_2();
        }
    }
```

2. use `dynamic` keyword instead of `object` type. Try this:

   ```
   static void Main()
   {
       dynamic a;
       bool flag = true;


       if (flag)
           a = new Test1();
       else
           a = new Test2();


       if (a is Test1)
           a.True_1();        //So, there will be no error anymore
       else
           a.True_2();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a third party DLL that contains a class...

```
class ThirdPartyClass
{
    public bool Foo { get { return true;} }
}
```

And you want to create your own class that has a method or property in common with the third party class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public bool Foo { get { return true;} }
}
```

As you mention, what you'd normally do is add an interface to the third party class, and then implement that interface in your own class. But you can't do that, as you also pointed out. And without an interface in common, you're stuck with that clunky if/then construct.

If I correctly understand your situation, you can deal with it as follow.  Extend the third party class to add the interface, like so:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    bool Foo { get; }
}

class MyThirdPartyClass : ThirdPartyClass, IMyInterface
{
}
```

Since `Foo` is public, it will get inherited and be available, and satisfy the interface. And now you can create your own class too:

```
class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public bool Foo { get { return true; }}
}
```

And you can use them interchangeably:

```
IMyInterface a = new MyThirdPartyClass();
IMyInterface b = new MyClass();
bool c = a.Foo; 
bool d = b.Foo;
```

That's how I would do it.

You may run into a problem if the third party class is [sealed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed). If that is the case, you have to wrap it instead of inheriting from it:

```
class MyThirdPartyClassWrapper : IMyInterface
{
    private readonly ThirdPartyClass _wrappedInstance = new ThirdPartyClass();

    public bool Foo { get { return _wrappedInstance.Foo; } }
}
```

And then it'll still work:

```
IMyInterface a = new MyThirdPartyClassWrapper();
IMyInterface b = new MyClass();
bool c = a.Foo; 
bool d = b.Foo;
```