# Most efficient way of dealing with DBNull in .NET

Tags: .net, sql, dbnull

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to deal with DBNull's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-dbnulls)

What is the most efficient syntax in .NET to set a variable that has a value of DBNull (aka SQL null value being returned)?  I remember reading something that was put into .NET 3.0 for this sort of thing.  Lets assume the variable I'm setting has a type of DateTime.

Common error:
Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Date' is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateTime is a value type, and can only contain valid date/times.  Typically the way this is handled is to check your value returned from teh database to see if it's DBNull.Value, and if so set the DateTime to a special value like DateTime.MinValue which represents Null.

Alternatively you can use DateTime? which is a nullable DateTime datatype and you can actually assign it null (regular .Net null, not DBNull).

```
DateTime foo;
if (row["SomeField"] == DBNull.Value) {
    foo = DateTime.MinValue;
} else {
    foo = (DateTime)row["SomeField"];
}
```

You can make this syntax a little bit nicer by creating an extension method on a DataRow like so:

```
public static void ToDateTime(this DataRow row, string columnName) {
    if (row[columnName] == DBNull.Value) {
        return DateTime.MinValue;
    } else {
        return (DateTime)row[columnName];
    }
}
```

then you can rewrite the original code like this:

```
DateTime foo = row.ToDateTime("SomeField");
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually get around this by making the property in my class a NULLABLE type. This is especially relevant to the bool type, since by default, it has no value (neither true nor false).

```
public class MyDbTable
    {
        public int MyId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
        public bool? IsDirty { get; set; }
    }
```